# How do I shuffle an array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, shuffle

.shuffle() and .shuffled() are part of Swift

---

**Original historic question:**

How do I randomize or shuffle the elements within an array in Swift? For example, if my array consists of 52 playing cards, I want to **shuffle** the array in order to shuffle the deck.

Comment: @Mithrandir That's not true. In Ruby one would go for `array.shuffle`. There's no need to implement your own version. I guess OP was looking for something similar.

Answer (score 664, accepted):

This answer details how to shuffle with a fast and uniform algorithm (Fisher-Yates) in Swift 4.2+ and how to add the same feature in the various previous versions of Swift. The naming and behavior for each Swift version matches the mutating and nonmutating sorting methods for that version.

## Swift 4.2+

[`shuffle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994753-shuffle) and [`shuffled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994757-shuffled) are native starting Swift 4.2. Example usage:

```
let x = [1, 2, 3].shuffled()
// x == [2, 3, 1]

let fiveStrings = stride(from: 0, through: 100, by: 5).map(String.init).shuffled()
// fiveStrings == ["20", "45", "70", "30", ...]

var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
numbers.shuffle()
// numbers == [3, 2, 1, 4]
```

## Swift 4.0 and 4.1

These extensions add a `shuffle()` method to any mutable collection (arrays and unsafe mutable buffers) and a `shuffled()` method to any sequence:

```
extension MutableCollection {
    /// Shuffles the contents of this collection.
    mutating func shuffle() {
        let c = count
        guard c > 1 else { return }

        for (firstUnshuffled, unshuffledCount) in zip(indices, stride(from: c, to: 1, by: -1)) {
            // Change `Int` in the next line to `IndexDistance` in < Swift 4.1
            let d: Int = numericCast(arc4random_uniform(numericCast(unshuffledCount)))
            let i = index(firstUnshuffled, offsetBy: d)
            swapAt(firstUnshuffled, i)
        }
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    /// Returns an array with the contents of this sequence, shuffled.
    func shuffled() -> [Element] {
        var result = Array(self)
        result.shuffle()
        return result
    }
}
```

Same usage as in Swift 4.2 examples above.

---

## Swift 3

These extensions add a `shuffle()` method to any mutable collection and a `shuffled()` method to any sequence:

```
extension MutableCollection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
    /// Shuffles the contents of this collection.
    mutating func shuffle() {
        let c = count
        guard c > 1 else { return }

        for (firstUnshuffled , unshuffledCount) in zip(indices, stride(from: c, to: 1, by: -1)) {
            // Change `Int` in the next line to `IndexDistance` in < Swift 3.2
            let d: Int = numericCast(arc4random_uniform(numericCast(unshuffledCount)))
            guard d != 0 else { continue }
            let i = index(firstUnshuffled, offsetBy: d)
            self.swapAt(firstUnshuffled, i)
        }
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    /// Returns an array with the contents of this sequence, shuffled.
    func shuffled() -> [Iterator.Element] {
        var result = Array(self)
        result.shuffle()
        return result
    }
}
```

Same usage as in Swift 4.2 examples above.

---

## Swift 2

(obsolete language: you can't use Swift 2.x to publish on iTunes Connect starting July 2018)

```
extension MutableCollectionType where Index == Int {
    /// Shuffle the elements of `self` in-place.
    mutating func shuffleInPlace() {
        // empty and single-element collections don't shuffle
        if count < 2 { return }

        for i in startIndex ..< endIndex - 1 {
            let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - i))) + i
            guard i != j else { continue }
            swap(&self[i], &self[j])
        }
    }
}

extension CollectionType {
    /// Return a copy of `self` with its elements shuffled.
    func shuffle() -> [Generator.Element] {
        var list = Array(self)
        list.shuffleInPlace()
        return list
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[1, 2, 3].shuffle()
// [2, 3, 1]

let fiveStrings = 0.stride(through: 100, by: 5).map(String.init).shuffle()
// ["20", "45", "70", "30", ...]

var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
numbers.shuffleInPlace()
// [3, 2, 1, 4]
```

---

## Swift 1.2

(obsolete language: you can't use Swift 1.x to publish on iTunes Connect starting July 2018)

### `shuffle` as a mutating array method

This extension will let you shuffle a mutable `Array` instance in place:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func shuffle() {
        if count < 2 { return }
        for i in 0..<(count - 1) {
            let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - i))) + i
            swap(&self[i], &self[j])
        }
    }
}
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
numbers.shuffle()                     // e.g., numbers == [6, 1, 8, 3, 2, 4, 7, 5]
```

### `shuffled` as a non-mutating array method

This extension will let you retrieve a shuffled copy of an `Array` instance:

```
extension Array {
    func shuffled() -> [T] {
        if count < 2 { return self }
        var list = self
        for i in 0..<(list.count - 1) {
            let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(list.count - i))) + i
            swap(&list[i], &list[j])
        }
        return list
    }
}
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
let mixedup = numbers.shuffled()     // e.g., mixedup == [6, 1, 8, 3, 2, 4, 7, 5]
```

Comment: How would you turn this into an array extension ?

Comment: @NateCook thanks, great answer, my extension collection just got bigger

Comment: In case you want the function version in Swift 1.2, it needs a bit of updating as `countElements` is gone, and it’s replacement, `count`, now returns a `T.Index.Distance` so the constraint needs to be on `C.Index.Distance == Int`.  This version should work: https://gist.github.com/airspeedswift/03d07a9dc86fabdc370f

Comment: Just being picky here but are your commented sections a result of this actual algorithm? I thought the Fisher Yates shuffle did not allow any object to be in the position it started in and "7" and "goodbye" in your example haven't moved. Or am I not reading the code right? Excellent answer though. I have used it many times. :-D

Comment: Those are the actual output—Fisher-Yates should return an unbiased random permutation of the source, so there's no requirement that a particular element should move. There *is* a guarantee that no element moves more than once, but sometimes the "move" is to the same index. The simplest case is to think about `[1, 2].shuffled()`—should that return `[2, 1]` every time?

Comment: I added `if count > 0` at the top of the mutating array function, to prevent receiving a "fatal error: Can't form Range with end < start" when it is passed an empty array.

Comment: @CarlSmith or list.isEmpty

Comment: Your Swift 2.0 shuffle() method always returns an Array, regardless of the CollectionType. Is there not a way to improve it to always return the same CollectionType in Swift 2.0?

Comment: swap is giving a runtime error in the latest xcode beta: fatal error: swapping a location with itself is not supported. Any workarounds?

Comment: @Jan: Yes, add `guard i != j else { continue }` before the swap. I filed a radar, but the new behavior is intentional.

Comment: added 'import Foundation' so that it works inside a Playground

Comment: For Swift 3, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843647/shufle-array-swift-3, perhaps you want to add that to your answer.

Comment: Actually `shuffleInPlace` can crash if the collection indices do not start at zero, e.g. for an array slice. `for i in 0..<count - 1`  should be `for i in startIndex ..< endIndex - 1` (and then the conversion to Swift 3 becomes almost trivial).

Comment: @MartinR: Good catch, thank you! Now this works (Swift 2 syntax): `var numbers = Array(1...10); number[5..<10].shuffleInPlace()`

Comment: fatal error: swapping a location with itself is not supported

Comment: IndexDistance is deprecated in Swift 4.1

Comment: This does not work in XCode playgrounds `cannot invoke index with an argument list of type self.index, offsetBy: int`

Comment: It would have been easier to read if you followed swift naming conventions and didn't use single letter names for variables.

Answer (score 135):

**Edit:** As noted in other answers, Swift 4.2 [finally](http://daringfireball.net) adds random number generation to the standard library, complete with array shuffling.

However, the `GKRandom` / `GKRandomDistribution` suite in GameplayKit can still be useful with the new `RandomNumberGenerator` protocol — if you add extensions to the GameplayKit RNGs to conform to the new standard library protocol, you can easily get:

- sendable RNGs (that can reproduce a "random" sequence when needed for testing)
- RNGs that sacrifice robustness for speed
- RNGs that produce non-uniform distributions

...and still make use of the nice new "native" random APIs in Swift.

The rest of this answer concerns such RNGs and/or their use in older Swift compilers.

---

There are some good answers here already, as well as some good illustrations of why writing your own shuffle can be error-prone if you're not careful.

In iOS 9, macOS 10.11, and tvOS 9 (or later), you don't have to write your own. There's [an efficient, correct implementation of Fisher-Yates](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GKRandomSource_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKRandomSource/arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray:) in GameplayKit (which, despite the name, is not just for games).

If you just want a unique shuffle:

```
let shuffled = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: array)
```

If you want to be able to replicate a shuffle or series of shuffles, choose and seed a specific random source; e.g.

```
let lcg = GKLinearCongruentialRandomSource(seed: mySeedValue)
let shuffled = lcg.arrayByShufflingObjects(in: array)
```

In iOS 10 / macOS 10.12 / tvOS 10, there's also a convenience syntax for shuffling via an extension on `NSArray`. Of course, that's a little cumbersome when you're using a Swift `Array` (and it loses its element type on coming back to Swift):

```
let shuffled1 = (array as NSArray).shuffled(using: random) // -> [Any]
let shuffled2 = (array as NSArray).shuffled() // use default random source
```

But it's pretty easy to make a type-preserving Swift wrapper for it:

```
extension Array {
    func shuffled(using source: GKRandomSource) -> [Element] {
        return (self as NSArray).shuffled(using: source) as! [Element]
    }
    func shuffled() -> [Element] {
        return (self as NSArray).shuffled() as! [Element]
    }
}
let shuffled3 = array.shuffled(using: random)
let shuffled4 = array.shuffled()
```

Comment: Makes me wonder what other helpful utilities can be found in GameplayKit that I have never explored!

Comment: Graph search, tree search, rule systems... [lots of stuff](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GameplayKit_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015199) that's helpful both in game design and otherwise.

Comment: In Swift 3/iOS 10, this has been changed to: `let shuffled = lcg.arrayByShufflingObjects(in: array)`

Answer (score 31):

In **Swift 2.0**, GameplayKit may come to the rescue! (supported by **iOS9** or later)

```
import GameplayKit

func shuffle() {
    array = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(array)
}
```

Comment: importing GameplayKit just to get shuffled array doesn't sound like a great idea

Comment: Why? It's part of the system, doesn't add to the binary.

Comment: You can also scope the import to simply `import GameplayKit.GKRandomSource`

Answer (score 27):

Here's something possibly a little shorter:

```
sorted(a) {_, _ in arc4random() % 2 == 0}
```

Comment: @moby The `sort` function needs a closure to order elements. This closure takes two parameters (elem1, elem2) and must return true if the first value should appear before the second value, and false otherwise. If we return a random boolean instead... then we just mix  up the whole thing :)

Comment: @moby Last note: if you don't care about the param names (our case here), one can replace the name with a `_`.

Comment: A new answer to deal with the "sort/sorted" changes in beta5: `
sorted(a) {_, _ in arc4random() % 2 == 0}`

Comment: Is this mathematically equivalent to shuffling the array (processing each element exactly one time)?

Comment: @frankls95 good question. If one thinks about it, though, one will find that good shuffling cannot be done in a o(n) fashion. In fact, what is shuffling if not sorting... backward in time? Therefore, I believe that shuffling must be done in o(n log n) just like quicksort... which the `sort` function must probably use.

Comment: Any mathematician here to confirm or disprove?

Comment: As pjs pointed out in response to another very similar answer, this will _not_ generate uniform distribution of results. Use [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle) as shown in Nate Cook's answer.

Comment: This is a clever trick, but is abysmal in terms of quality of the shuffle. For one, this closure should use `arc4random_uniform()`, becuse it's currently subject to the modulo bias. Secondly,the output depends very strongly on the sorting algorithm (which isn't known to us without looking at the source).

Comment: Continuing with this simpler approach, this seems to work quite nicely:

```collection.sorted { _,_ in arc4random_uniform(1) == 0 }```

Comment: I prefer the following  arr.sort {_,_ in return arc4random() & 1 == 0 }, as it shuffles in place, without need to  reassign

Answer (score 10):

As of swift 4.2 there are two handy functions:

```
// shuffles the array in place
myArray.shuffle()
```

and

```
// generates a new array with shuffled elements of the old array
let newArray = myArray.shuffled()
```

Answer (score 8):

Taking [Nate's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24029847/250190) algorithm I wanted to see how this would look with Swift 2 and protocol extensions.

This is what I came up with.

```
extension MutableCollectionType where Self.Index == Int {
    mutating func shuffleInPlace() {
        let c = self.count
        for i in 0..<(c - 1) {
            let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(c - i))) + i
            swap(&self[i], &self[j])
        }
    }
}

extension MutableCollectionType where Self.Index == Int {
    func shuffle() -> Self {
        var r = self
        let c = self.count
        for i in 0..<(c - 1) {
            let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(c - i))) + i
            swap(&r[i], &r[j])
        }
        return r
    }
}
```

Now, any `MutableCollectionType` can use these methods given it uses `Int` as an `Index`

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I had some problems of swapping objects in Array.  Then I scratched my head and went for reinventing the wheel.

```
// swift 3.0 ready
extension Array {

    func shuffled() -> [Element] {
        var results = [Element]()
        var indexes = (0 ..< count).map { $0 }
        while indexes.count > 0 {
            let indexOfIndexes = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(indexes.count)))
            let index = indexes[indexOfIndexes]
            results.append(self[index])
            indexes.remove(at: indexOfIndexes)
        }
        return results
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a version of [Nate's implementation of the Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24029847/1187415) for **Swift 4**
(Xcode 9).

```
extension MutableCollection {
    /// Shuffle the elements of `self` in-place.
    mutating func shuffle() {
        for i in indices.dropLast() {
            let diff = distance(from: i, to: endIndex)
            let j = index(i, offsetBy: numericCast(arc4random_uniform(numericCast(diff))))
            swapAt(i, j)
        }
    }
}

extension Collection {
    /// Return a copy of `self` with its elements shuffled
    func shuffled() -> [Element] {
        var list = Array(self)
        list.shuffle()
        return list
    }
}
```

The changes are:

- The constraint `Indices.Iterator.Element == Index` is now part
  of the `Collection` protocol, and need not be imposed on the
  extension anymore.
- Exchanging elements must done by calling `swapAt()` on the collection,
  compare [SE-0173 Add `MutableCollection.swapAt(_:_:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0173-swap-indices.md).
- `Element` is an alias for `Iterator.Element`.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4**
Shuffle the elements of an array in a for loop where i is the mixing ratio

```
var cards = [Int]() //Some Array
let i = 4 // is the mixing ratio
func shuffleCards() {
    for _ in 0 ..< cards.count * i {
        let card = cards.remove(at: Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cards.count))))
        cards.insert(card, at: Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(cards.count))))
    }
}
```

Or with extension Int

```
func shuffleCards() {
    for _ in 0 ..< cards.count * i {
        let card = cards.remove(at: cards.count.arc4random)
        cards.insert(card, at: cards.count.arc4random)
    }
}
extension Int {
    var arc4random: Int {
        if self > 0 {
            print("Arc for random positiv self \(Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self))))")
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self)))
        } else if self < 0 {
            print("Arc for random negotiv self \(-Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(abs(self)))))")
            return -Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(abs(self))))
        } else {
            print("Arc for random equal 0")
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use:

```
func newShuffledArray(array:NSArray) -> NSArray {
    var mutableArray = array.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
    var count = mutableArray.count
    if count>1 {
        for var i=count-1;i>0;--i{
            mutableArray.exchangeObjectAtIndex(i, withObjectAtIndex: Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(i+1))))
        }
    }
    return mutableArray as NSArray
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With Swift 3, if you want to shuffle an array in place or get a new shuffled array from an array, [`AnyIterator`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anyiterator) can help you. The idea is to create an array of indices from your array, to shuffle those indices with an `AnyIterator` instance and [`swap(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1540890-swap) function and to map each element of this `AnyIterator` instance with the array's corresponding element.

---

The following Playground code shows how it works:

```
import Darwin // required for arc4random_uniform

let array = ["Jock", "Ellie", "Sue Ellen", "Bobby", "JR", "Pamela"]
var indexArray = Array(array.indices)
var index = indexArray.endIndex

let indexIterator: AnyIterator<Int> = AnyIterator {
    guard let nextIndex = indexArray.index(index, offsetBy: -1, limitedBy: indexArray.startIndex)
        else { return nil }

    index = nextIndex
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(index)))
    if randomIndex != index {
        swap(&indexArray[randomIndex], &indexArray[index])
    }

    return indexArray[index]
}

let newArray = indexIterator.map { array[$0] }
print(newArray) // may print: ["Jock", "Ellie", "Sue Ellen", "JR", "Pamela", "Bobby"]
```

---

You can refactor the previous code and create a `shuffled()` function inside an `Array` extension in order to get a new shuffled array from an array:

```
import Darwin // required for arc4random_uniform

extension Array {

    func shuffled() -> Array<Element> {
        var indexArray = Array<Int>(indices)        
        var index = indexArray.endIndex

        let indexIterator = AnyIterator<Int> {
            guard let nextIndex = indexArray.index(index, offsetBy: -1, limitedBy: indexArray.startIndex)
                else { return nil }

            index = nextIndex                
            let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(index)))
            if randomIndex != index {
                swap(&indexArray[randomIndex], &indexArray[index])
            }

            return indexArray[index]
        }

        return indexIterator.map { self[$0] }
    }

}
```

*Usage:*

```
let array = ["Jock", "Ellie", "Sue Ellen", "Bobby", "JR", "Pamela"]
let newArray = array.shuffled()
print(newArray) // may print: ["Bobby", "Pamela", "Jock", "Ellie", "JR", "Sue Ellen"]
```

```
let emptyArray = [String]()
let newEmptyArray = emptyArray.shuffled()
print(newEmptyArray) // prints: []
```

---

As an alternative to the previous code, you can create a `shuffle()` function inside an `Array` extension in order to shuffle an array in place:

```
import Darwin // required for arc4random_uniform

extension Array {

    mutating func shuffle() {
        var indexArray = Array<Int>(indices)
        var index = indexArray.endIndex

        let indexIterator = AnyIterator<Int> {
            guard let nextIndex = indexArray.index(index, offsetBy: -1, limitedBy: indexArray.startIndex)
                else { return nil }

            index = nextIndex                
            let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(index)))
            if randomIndex != index {
                swap(&indexArray[randomIndex], &indexArray[index])
            }

            return indexArray[index]
        }

        self = indexIterator.map { self[$0] }
    }

}
```

*Usage:*

```
var mutatingArray = ["Jock", "Ellie", "Sue Ellen", "Bobby", "JR", "Pamela"]
mutatingArray.shuffle()
print(mutatingArray) // may print ["Sue Ellen", "Pamela", "Jock", "Ellie", "Bobby", "JR"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 solution, following @Nate Cook answer: (work if the index starts with 0, see comments below)

```
extension Collection {
    /// Return a copy of `self` with its elements shuffled
    func shuffle() -> [Generator.Element] {
        var list = Array(self)
        list.shuffleInPlace()
        return list
    } }

extension MutableCollection where Index == Int {
    /// Shuffle the elements of `self` in-place.
    mutating func shuffleInPlace() {
        // empty and single-element collections don't shuffle
        if count < 2 { return }
        let countInt = count as! Int

    for i in 0..<countInt - 1 {
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(countInt - i))) + i
            guard i != j else { continue }
            swap(&self[i], &self[j])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This can crash if the collection indices do start at 0, e.g. for an array slice. Try to run `var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6][3..<6]; a.shuffleInPlace()` several times. – See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37843901/1187415 for a correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is how its done in a Simplest way.`import Gamplaykit` to your VC and use the below code. Tested in Xcode 8.

```
 import GameplayKit

 let array: NSArray = ["Jock", "Ellie", "Sue Ellen", "Bobby", "JR", "Pamela"]

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(array.shuffled())  
}
```

If you want to get a shuffled String from an Array you can use below code..

```
func suffleString() {

    let ShuffleArray = array.shuffled()

    suffleString.text = ShuffleArray.first as? String

    print(suffleString.text!)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Swift 4.2**, there is now a method for both a [mutable `shuffle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994753-shuffle) and [immutable `shuffled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994757-shuffled). You can read more about the random generation and array stuff [here](https://learningswift.brightdigit.com/swift-4-2-random-changes-wwdc-2018/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use generic `swap` function as well and implement mentioned Fisher-Yates:

```
for idx in 0..<arr.count {
  let rnd = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(idx)))
  if rnd != idx {
    swap(&arr[idx], &arr[rnd])
  }
}
```

or less verbose:

```
for idx in 0..<steps.count {
  swap(&steps[idx], &steps[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(idx)))])
}
```

Comment: This suffers from, at the very least, a serious _off by one_ error [described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle) whereby a value is _always_ swapped from its original position. This is remedied with `let rnd = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(idx + 1)))`. Also, in FY, you generally iterate from `arr.count - 1` down to `1` (or if you iterate from `0` to `arr.count - 1`, you pick index like Nate shows in accepted answer). See [Modern Algorithm section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) of Fisher-Yates discussion.

Answer (score 1):

works!!. organisms is the array to shuffle.

```
extension Array
{
    /** Randomizes the order of an array's elements. */
    mutating func shuffle()
    {
        for _ in 0..<10
        {
            sort { (_,_) in arc4random() < arc4random() }
        }
    }
}

var organisms = [
    "ant",  "bacteria", "cougar",
    "dog",  "elephant", "firefly",
    "goat", "hedgehog", "iguana"]

print("Original: \(organisms)")

organisms.shuffle()

print("Shuffled: \(organisms)")
```

Answer (score 1):

## Working Array Extension (mutating & non-mutating)

### Swift 4.1 / Xcode 9

The top answer is deprecated, so I took it upon myself to create my own extension to shuffle an array in the newest version of Swift, Swift 4.1 (Xcode 9):

```swift
extension Array {

// Non-mutating shuffle
    var shuffled : Array {
        let totalCount : Int = self.count
        var shuffledArray : Array = []
        var count : Int = totalCount
        var tempArray : Array = self
        for _ in 0..<totalCount {
            let randomIndex : Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
            let randomElement : Element = tempArray.remove(at: randomIndex)
            shuffledArray.append(randomElement)
            count -= 1
        }
        return shuffledArray
    }

// Mutating shuffle
    mutating func shuffle() {
        let totalCount : Int = self.count
        var shuffledArray : Array = []
        var count : Int = totalCount
        var tempArray : Array = self
        for _ in 0..<totalCount {
            let randomIndex : Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
            let randomElement : Element = tempArray.remove(at: randomIndex)
            shuffledArray.append(randomElement)
            count -= 1
        }
        self = shuffledArray
    }
}
```

---

### Call Non-Mutating Shuffle `[Array] -> [Array]`:

```swift
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

print(array.shuffled)
```

This prints `array` in a random order.

---

### Call Mutating Shuffle `[Array] = [Array]`:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

array.shuffle() 
// The array has now been mutated and contains all of its initial 
// values, but in a randomized shuffled order

print(array)
```

This prints `array` in its current order, which has already been randomly shuffled.

---

**Hopes this works for everybody, if you have any questions, suggestions, or comments, feel free to ask!**

Answer (score 1):

**In SWIFT 4**

```
func createShuffledSequenceOfNumbers(max:UInt)->[UInt] {

    var array:[UInt]! = []
    var myArray:[UInt]! = []
    for i in 1...max {
        myArray.append(i)
    }
    for i in 1...max {
        array.append(i)
    }
    var tempArray:[Int]! = []
    for index in 0...(myArray.count - 1) {

        var isNotFinded:Bool = true
        while(isNotFinded){

            let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myArray.count))
            let randomIndex = Int(randomNumber)

            if(!tempArray.contains(randomIndex)){
                tempArray.append(randomIndex)

                array[randomIndex] = myArray[index]
                isNotFinded = false
            }
        }
    }

    return array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use simple Swift For loop function use this ->

```
var arrayItems = ["A1", "B2", "C3", "D4", "E5", "F6", "G7", "H8", "X9", "Y10", "Z11"]
var shuffledArray = [String]()

for i in 0..<arrayItems.count
{
    let randomObject = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(items.count)))

    shuffledArray.append(items[randomObject])

    items.remove(at: randomObject)
}

print(shuffledArray)
```

---

Swift Array suffle using extension ->

```
extension Array {
    // Order Randomize
    mutating func shuffle() {
        for _ in 0..<count {
            sort { (_,_) in arc4random() < arc4random() }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to shuffle one array with a seed in Swift 3.0.

```
extension MutableCollection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
    mutating func shuffle() {
        let c = count
        guard c > 1 else { return }


        for (firstUnshuffled , unshuffledCount) in zip(indices, stride(from: c, to: 1, by: -1)) {
            srand48(seedNumber)
            let number:Int = numericCast(unshuffledCount)
            let r = floor(drand48() * Double(number))

            let d: IndexDistance = numericCast(Int(r))
            guard d != 0 else { continue }
            let i = index(firstUnshuffled, offsetBy: d)
            swap(&self[firstUnshuffled], &self[i])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let shuffl = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: arrayObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
import GameplayKit

extension Collection {
    func shuffled() -> [Iterator.Element] {
        let shuffledArray = (self as? NSArray)?.shuffled()
        let outputArray = shuffledArray as? [Iterator.Element]
        return outputArray ?? []
    }
    mutating func shuffle() {
        if let selfShuffled = self.shuffled() as? Self {
            self = selfShuffled
        }
    }
}

// Usage example:

var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
numbers.shuffle()

print(numbers) // output example: [2, 3, 5, 4, 1]

print([10, "hi", 9.0].shuffled()) // output example: [hi, 10, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Example:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func shuffled() {
        for _ in self {
            // generate random indexes that will be swapped
            var (a, b) = (Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count - 1))), Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count - 1))))
            if a == b { // if the same indexes are generated swap the first and last
                a = 0
                b = self.count - 1
            }
            swap(&self[a], &self[b])
        }
    }
}

var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
array.shuffled()
print(array) // [9, 8, 3, 5, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1, 10]
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's some code that runs in playground. You won't need to import Darwin in an actual Xcode project.

```
import darwin

var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

func shuffle<ItemType>(item1: ItemType, item2: ItemType) -> Bool {
    return drand48() > 0.5
}

sort(a, shuffle)

println(a)
```

Comment: This gives a non-uniform distribution of the results.  It also will be O(n log n), where a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_Shuffle) would give uniformly distributed results in O(n) time.

Comment: Also `drand48()` gives the same pseudo random numbers everytime, unless you set a seed with like `srand48(Int(arc4random()))`

Answer (score -3):

It stop at "swap(&self[i], &self[j])" when I upgrade the xCode version to 7.4 beta.
fatal error: swapping a location with itself is not supported

> I found the reason that i = j (function of swap will exploded)

So I add a condition as below

```
if (i != j){
    swap(&list[i], &list[j])
}
```

YA! It's OK for me.

Comment: This appears to be a comment on [Chris's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30838749/1677912), not an answer to the original question.