# How to exchange elements in swift array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsmutablearray

I have one simple array like:

```
var cellOrder = [1,2,3,4]
```

I want to exchange elements like suppose a second element with first element.

And result will be:

```
[2,1,3,4]
```

I know we can use `exchangeObjectAtIndex` with `NSMutableArray` But I want to use swift array. Any ways to do same with swift `[Int]` array?

Comment: You should know about `swap()` because *you* posted a question about it: [fatal error: swapping a location with itself is not supported with Swift 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689753/fatal-error-swapping-a-location-with-itself-is-not-supported-with-swift-2-0)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use `swap`:

```
var cellOrder = [1,2,3,4]
swap(&cellOrder[0], &cellOrder[1])
```

Alternately, you can just assign it as a tuple:

```
(cellOrder[0], cellOrder[1]) = (cellOrder[1], cellOrder[0])
```

Comment: In swift 4 it's now `swapAt`

Comment: `swapAt` is a different function that takes indexes rather than `inout` values. It can be be used to solve this problem too, but is not a replacement for `swap` (which still exists in Swift 4).

Comment: I had issues implementing this answer. I got this particular error while trying to swap out values. "Simultaneous accesses to 0x108e19918, but modification requires exclusive access."
use `swap` worked better for me.

Comment: To expand on what the people above are saying, instead of doing 'swap(&cellOrder[0], &cellOrder[1])' in Swift 4 you would now do 'swapAt(0, 1)', so it's simpler now. And @RobNapier's second solution still works in Swift 4: you can still get the job done by assigning it as a tuple.

Comment: Can you give an example of where `swap` can be applied but `swap(at:)` can't?

Comment: @Honey Any case where it's not a Collection. `swap(&x, &y)`.

Comment: @RobNapier you say "[swapAt] is not a replacement for swap"... in cases where it is available, it is 100% interchangeable right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "where it's available." The two functions have different interfaces. They don't do the same things.

Answer (score 51):

**Swift 4**

[`swapAt(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2893281-swapat):

```
cellOrder.swapAt(index0, index1)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16686681)

Comment: @basvk I think it answers the question - it shows how to "swap two elements" from the array. And it's a valid answer to the question (also correct).

Comment: @basvk Thanks for your advise.To answer this question,`cellOrder.swapAt(0, 1)`should be better to understand. And also thanks @Zizouz212 .

Comment: Yes this is valid answer for swift 4.0 version.

Answer (score 8):

One option is:

```
cellOrder[0...1] = [cellOrder[1], cellOrder[0]]
```

Answer (score 4):

### Details

- Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8), Swift 5

### Base (unsafe but fast) variant

> **unsafe** - means that you can catch fatal error when you will try to make a swap using wrong (out of the range) index of the element in array

```
var array = [1,2,3,4]
// way 1
(array[0],array[1]) = (array[1],array[0])
// way 2
array.swapAt(2, 3)

print(array)
```

### Solution of safe swap

- save swap attempt (checking indexes)
- possible to know what index wrong

> do not use this solution when you have to swap a lot of elements in the loop. This solution validates both (i,j) indexes (add some extra logic) in the swap functions which will make your code slower than usage of standard `arr.swapAt(i,j)`. It is perfect for single swaps or for small array. But, if you will decide to use standard `arr.swapAt(i,j)` you will have to check indexes manually or to be sure that indexes are not out of the range.

```
import Foundation

enum SwapError: Error {
    case wrongFirstIndex
    case wrongSecondIndex
}

extension Array {
    mutating func detailedSafeSwapAt(_ i: Int, _ j: Int) throws {
        if !(0..<count ~= i) { throw SwapError.wrongFirstIndex }
        if !(0..<count ~= j) { throw SwapError.wrongSecondIndex }
        swapAt(i, j)
    }

    @discardableResult mutating func safeSwapAt(_ i: Int, _ j: Int) -> Bool {
        do {
            try detailedSafeSwapAt(i, j)
            return true
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage of safe swap

```
result = arr.safeSwapAt(5, 2)

//or
if arr.safeSwapAt(5, 2) {
    //Success
} else {
    //Fail
}

//or
arr.safeSwapAt(4, 8)

//or
do {
    try arr.detailedSafeSwapAt(4, 8)
} catch let error as SwapError {
    switch error {
    case .wrongFirstIndex: print("Error 1")
    case .wrongSecondIndex: print("Error 2")
    }
}
```

### Full sample of safe swap

```
var arr = [10,20,30,40,50]
print("Original array: \(arr)")

print("\nSample 1 (with returning Bool = true): ")
var result = arr.safeSwapAt(1, 2)
print("Result: " + (result ? "Success" : "Fail"))
print("Array: \(arr)")

print("\nSample 2 (with returning Bool = false):")
result = arr.safeSwapAt(5, 2)
print("Result: " + (result ? "Success" : "Fail"))
print("Array: \(arr)")

print("\nSample 3 (without returning value):")
arr.safeSwapAt(4, 8)
print("Array: \(arr)")

print("\nSample 4 (with catching error):")
do {
    try arr.detailedSafeSwapAt(4, 8)
} catch let error as SwapError {
    switch error {
    case .wrongFirstIndex: print("Error 1")
    case .wrongSecondIndex: print("Error 2")
    }
}
print("Array: \(arr)")


print("\nSample 5 (with catching error):")
do {
    try arr.detailedSafeSwapAt(7, 1)
} catch let error as SwapError {
    print(error)
}
print("Array: \(arr)")
```

### Full sample log of safe swap

```
Original array: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

Sample 1 (with returning Bool = true): 
Result: Success
Array: [10, 30, 20, 40, 50]

Sample 2 (with returning Bool = false):
Result: Fail
Array: [10, 30, 20, 40, 50]

Sample 3 (without returning value):
Array: [10, 30, 20, 40, 50]

Sample 4 (with catching error):
Error 2
Array: [10, 30, 20, 40, 50]

Sample 5 (with catching error):
wrongFirstIndex
Array: [10, 30, 20, 40, 50]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use swapAt method,

```
var arr = [10,20,30,40,50]
arr.swapAt(2, 3)
```

Use the index to swap element.