# How to get a random image from a folder in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

So far I have created a folder of images and I am able to assign 1 of the images to a `UIImageView`.

But what I want to do now is create a random generator, that will pick a random image from the folder, so if I was to create a button, I could display all of the images separately and randomly on a single `UIImageView`.

However, this folder is going to have more than 100 images, so I don't want to hard code each one into an array. Also, the names of the image has to be unique to the image itself.

I have been searching online but cannot find information on how to code what will suit my needs. So how would I get and display a random image(s) from a folder in swift?

Comment: Just get your folder contents (array of urls) and randomly pick one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259332/get-random-elements-from-array-in-swift/27261991?s=3|0.0664#27261991 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721418/getting-list-of-files-in-documents-folder/27722526?s=1|1.1551#27722526

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can name your images like this

```
image_0
image_1
image_2
```

Then use this code to populate your `UIImageView`

```
let numberOfImages: UInt32 = 100
let random = arc4random_uniform(numberOfImages)
let imageName = "image_\(random)"
imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
```

### Update

Since you don't want to rename your images you can create a plist file (type Array) where you put all the names of your images

[image]

And finally

```
func loadRandomImage() {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Images", ofType: "plist")!
    let names = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as! [String]
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(names.count)))
    let imageName = names[random]
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
}
```

Comment: The names don't matter, just get your folder contents, use its count to limit the random index generated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259332/get-random-elements-from-array-in-swift/27261991?s=3|0.0664#27261991

Comment: @AndrewMontague: Are you using `Assets.xcassets`? That's where you should put the images for a bunch of reasons

Comment: @AndrewMontague: Using Assets.xcassets is important, especially if you are making a game.

Comment: @AndrewMontague: I added a new section to my answer, please check it out. Or try the solution suggested by _@Leo Dabus_.

Comment: Thank you, this method works exactly for what I wanted, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

You either need to create an array of string filenames and pick a random filename from the array, or you need to use the file manager (`NSFileManager`) to get a list of the files in your folder and then pick from THAT array. Nether is very difficult.