# Interleaving the second half of an NSArray with the first half

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, sorting, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` containing ten custom objects in a particular order.

What I need is to rearrange the objects so that the second half of the array is interleaved with the first half:

Before: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
After: 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why not do it simple like:NSArray *arr = @[Object 1, Object 2, Object 3, Object 4, Object 5, Object 6, Object 7, Object 8, Object 9, Object 10];  =>  NSArray *results = @[arr[0], arr[5], arr[1], arr[6], arr[2], arr[7], arr[3], arr[8], arr[4], arr[9]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a `shuffle` (think shuffling a deck of cards - same data, different order).  The following method can be used to [swap two objects within a mutable array.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BCIJIGDB)

```
- (void)exchangeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx1
        withObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx2
```

You cannot enumerate over an array while you are modifying it, and I would refrain from looping over the elements of the array as well.  Instead, create a for-loop with an index and use [arc4random](http://nshipster.com/random/) to generate the second swap index.

```
for (NSUInteger n = 0; n < array.count; n++) {
    NSUInteger m = arc4random_uniform(array.count);
    [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:n withObjectAtIndex:m];
}
```

There's more sophistication that can be added like checking to see if `n == m` or negating some kind of bias but this should get you a "mostly" random sampling of the original array.

---

[Swift]

Swift exchange Method swaps two items in a mutable array.
    func exchangeObjectAtIndex(_ idx1: Int,
         withObjectAtIndex idx2: Int)

User Nate Cook provides several good [shuffling methods for `Swift` here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift)  I'm copying his mutating Array method here, as it is closest to the Objective-C method described above.

```
extension Array {
    mutating func shuffle() {
        for i in 0..<(count - 1) {
            let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - i))) + i
            exchangeObjectAtIndex(i, withObjectAtIndex: j)
        }
    }
}
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
numbers.shuffle()
```

Answer (score 1):

- (void)exchangeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx1 withObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx2
- (void)sortUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a second NSArray, in which you put your values in the order you want to? After that, if you wish to use the first array, you remove all items from it

```
[firstArray removeAllObjects];
```

then put the items back from the second array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [secondArray count]; i++)
{
[firstArray addObject: [secondArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```