# Generate random String without repeating in swift

Tags: swift, string, random, repeat

I want the function to generate random String without repeating.
For example this function maybe will print: ABCC

```
func randomString(length:Int) -> String {
let charSet = "ABCDEF"
var c = charSet.characters.map { String($0) }
var s:String = ""
for _ in (1...length) {
    s.append(c[Int(arc4random()) % c.count])
}
return s
} print(randomString(length: 4))
```

and i want print random unique string only, E.g : ABCD

Comment: Ever play a card game? Have you ever heard of the notion "shuffle"? Shuffle the characters and deal off the first four.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761557/shuffling-a-string-in-swift (of which your question is really just a duplicate)

Comment: or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845307/generate-random-alphanumeric-string-in-swift

Comment: "matt" sorry i don't found the answer

Comment: "iWheelBuy" i want function without repeating ( duplicating )

Comment: @Sami each time function is called it should produce new string? or the string should not contain duplicated characters?

Comment: @iWheelBuy not contain duplicated characters, thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
import GameplayKit

func randomString(length : Int) -> String {
    let charSet = Array("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".characters)
    let shuffled = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: charSet) as! [Character]
    let array = shuffled.prefix(length)
    return String(array)
}

print(randomString(length: 4))
```

Comment: Duplicate characters are possible with your answer

Comment: In what way?  The set of characters is shuffled.  None of them are duplicated.  The first `length` items is taken of the front of the shuffled array.  Where could the characters in the set become duplicated?

Comment: Array("ABCA".characters)

Comment: Given the code as written it will not generate duplicate characters.

Comment: Well, if you don't expect user to change the string - it will work. I expect that it might be changed and contain duplicate symbols.

Comment: I fully respect your right to assume that someone might choose to provide a non-unique charset from which to draw characters in creating the random string.  It seems rather unlikely to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
    let charSet = "ABCDEF"
    var charSetArray = charSet.characters.map { String($0) }
    var randArray: [String] = []
    while charSetArray.count > 0 {
        let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(charSetArray.count)))
        randArray.append(charSetArray[i])
        charSetArray.remove(at: i)
    }
    var output: String = ""
    for i in 0..<length {
        output.append(randArray[i])
    }
    return output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to use:

```
let randomString = "ABCDEF".random(length: 3)!
```

The return value is optional because the length might exceed the length of provided string.

Check out the full implementation:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

extension MutableCollection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
    mutating func shuffle() {
        let c = count
        guard c > 1 else { return }
        for (firstUnshuffled , unshuffledCount) in zip(indices, stride(from: c, to: 1, by: -1)) {
            let d: IndexDistance = numericCast(arc4random_uniform(numericCast(unshuffledCount)))
            guard d != 0 else { continue }
            let i = index(firstUnshuffled, offsetBy: d)
            swap(&self[firstUnshuffled], &self[i])
        }
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    func shuffled() -> [Iterator.Element] {
        var result = Array(self)
        result.shuffle()
        return result
    }
}

extension String {

    func random(length: Int) -> String? {
        let uniqueCharacters = Array(Set(characters.map({ String($0) })))
        guard length <= uniqueCharacters.count else { return nil }
        guard length > 0 else { return nil }
        return uniqueCharacters[0..<length].shuffled().joined()
    }
}
```