# Array of questions swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a quiz app in swift, while using example code from a tut. But the array of questions wont work.  The questions pop up, but in order. They don't come up randomly.  The code seems good, i don't know if that is a glitch in a iphone simulator or what. Here is my code.

```
import Foundation


class QuestionModel {

var questions: Array<Question>

init () {

    questions = []
    questions.append(Question(question: "What year did WWII start?", answers:["1939", "1940", "1941", "1942"], correctAnswerIndex: 0))
    questions.append(Question(question: "What day was D-Day?", answers:["June 6, 1944", "June 16, 1944", "June 26, 1944", "June 16, 1943"], correctAnswerIndex: 0))
    questions.append(Question(question: "What country was first invaded by Germany?", answers:["France", "Belgium", "Poland", "Russia"], correctAnswerIndex: 2))
    questions.append(Question(question:"Which article of the Weimar Constitution granted Hitler emergency powers essentially allowing him to avoid parliament? ", answers:["Article 26", "Article 86", "Article 3", "Article 48"], correctAnswerIndex: 3))
    questions.append(Question(question:"Who was the leader of the Soviet Union during World War II?", answers:["Lenin", "Trotsky", "Stalin",  "Khruschev"], correctAnswerIndex: 2))
    questions.append(Question(question:"The main Axis powers of WWII Consisted of: Germany, _____, _____", answers:["Italy, Japan", "Russia, Japan", "Romania, Russia", "Japan, Romania"], correctAnswerIndex: 0))

}



}

class Question {
var question: String
var answers: Array<String>
var correctAnswerIndex: Int

init(question: String,answers:Array<String>,correctAnswerIndex: Int) {
    self.question = question
    self.answers = answers
    self.correctAnswerIndex = correctAnswerIndex
}

func isGuessCorrect(guessNumber: Int) -> Bool {

    return correctAnswerIndex == Int(guessNumber-1)

}

}
```

Comment: you haven't written a code to get the questions randomly

Comment: What should i write to get the questions to randomly generate?

Comment: this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/24029847/1716859

Comment: thanks alot! But, sorry to ask. Where should i put one of these codes? And which one of the three should i use?

Comment: You have just written two classes. Now you have to write the code to make you of them. What is the tutorial you follow ?

Comment: The site where the tut is down, so i followed someones code on github. Here is the github link "https://github.com/mikest34/quiz_app_swift"

Answer (score 4):

[image: Output result of following code]

```
import UIKit

class QuestionModel {
    var questions: Array<Question>

    init () {
        questions = []
        questions.append(Question(question: "What year did WWII start?", answers:["1939", "1940", "1941", "1942"], correctAnswerIndex: 0))
        questions.append(Question(question: "What day was D-Day?", answers:["June 6, 1944", "June 16, 1944", "June 26, 1944", "June 16, 1943"], correctAnswerIndex: 0))
        questions.append(Question(question: "What country was first invaded by Germany?", answers:["France", "Belgium", "Poland", "Russia"], correctAnswerIndex: 2))
        questions.append(Question(question:"Which article of the Weimar Constitution granted Hitler emergency powers essentially allowing him to avoid parliament? ", answers:["Article 26", "Article 86", "Article 3", "Article 48"], correctAnswerIndex: 3))
        questions.append(Question(question:"Who was the leader of the Soviet Union during World War II?", answers:["Lenin", "Trotsky", "Stalin",  "Khruschev"], correctAnswerIndex: 2))
        questions.append(Question(question:"The main Axis powers of WWII Consisted of: Germany, _____, _____", answers:["Italy, Japan", "Russia, Japan", "Romania, Russia", "Japan, Romania"], correctAnswerIndex: 0))
    }
}

class Question {
    var question: String
    var answers: Array<String>
    var correctAnswerIndex: Int

    init(question: String,answers:Array<String>,correctAnswerIndex: Int) {
        self.question = question
        self.answers = answers
        self.correctAnswerIndex = correctAnswerIndex
    }

    func isGuessCorrect(guessNumber: Int) -> Bool {
       return correctAnswerIndex == Int(guessNumber-1)
    }

    var description:String {
        var str = "question = \(self.question)"
            for answer in answers {
                str += " " + answer
            }
        return str + " \(self.correctAnswerIndex)"
    }
 }

 var questionModel = QuestionModel()

 func randomQuestion(# queModel:QuestionModel){
     var questions = queModel.questions
     var randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count)))
     println(questions[randomIndex].description)
 }

 for _ in 1...5 {
     randomQuestion(queModel: questionModel)
 }
```

I have added a description method in Question class. May be it helps you.