# swift parse: How to shuffle objects after query?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

As far as I could find out, there is no easy random query function in parse. Is there a way to shuffle the objects after I queried them?

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {
            // shuffle objects here?
            PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects, withName:"Card", block: nil)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

EDIT:
I think the problem is at another point.
When I add like in the suggest post (thanks for that) the extension for shuffling, it works like a breeze!

BUT!

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

            println(objects)

            var shuffled = objects.shuffled()

            println(shuffled)

            PFObject.pinAllInBackground(shuffled, withName:"Card", block: nil)
```

As you can see, I pin the objects to the local storage.

On my next view I pull this data again out of the storage:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Card")
query.fromLocalDatastore()
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

     if (error == nil){
        println("from local store: \(objects)")
```

And here I have again the data in the same order as they are saved in the database... There are no shuffled items at all.

Isn't that strange?

Comment: possible duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift

Comment: I think the problem is that when you pull them from the local database or the parse database, either way, there's some sort of query.  I believe this defaults to be sorted by `updatedAt`.  You'll need to re-sort your objects each time you retrieve them and then sort them in memory.

Comment: Thanks Logan! That seems to be the right issue :( I don't think there is a way to prevent this kind of default sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Just take the objects and use a shuffle-method like provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift) on the objects:

```
var shuffledObjects = shuffle(objects)
```