# Re-create a random array from [AnyObject]

Tags: ios, swift

This is the array:

```
var objectArray = [AnyObject]()
```

I want to re-organise its objects in a totally random way. Something like:

```
objectArray = objectArray.random
```

Comment: Used self.objectArray = sorted(self.objectArray) {_, _ in arc4random() % 2 == 0}, works great

Comment: According to the comments to http://stackoverflow.com/a/24026828/1187415 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/24045300/1187415, that is *not* a good solution.