# How to generate a 4 digit random number with unique digits?

Tags: ios, swift

Like: `0123, 0913, 7612`
Not like: `0000, 1333, 3499`

Can it be done with `arcRandom()` in swift? Without array or loop?

Or If that impossible, how it be done with `arcRandom()` in any way ?

Comment: Ignore the computer. How would you do this if you just had a pencil and paper? What steps would you take?

Answer (score 7):

You just want to shuffle the digits and pick the number you want.

Start with [Nate Cook's Fischer-Yates shuffle code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift).

```
// Start with the digits
let digits = 0...9

// Shuffle them
let shuffledDigits = digits.shuffle()

// Take the number of digits you would like
let fourDigits = shuffledDigits.prefix(4)

// Add them up with place values
let value = fourDigits.reduce(0) {
    $0*10 + $1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var fourUniqueDigits: String {
    var result = ""
    repeat {
        // create a string with up to 4 leading zeros with a random number 0...9999
        result = String(format:"%04d", arc4random_uniform(10000) )
        // generate another random number if the set of characters count is less than four
    } while Set<Character>(result.characters).count < 4
    return result    // ran 5 times
}

fourUniqueDigits  // "3501"
fourUniqueDigits  // "8095"
fourUniqueDigits  // "9054"
fourUniqueDigits  // "4728"
fourUniqueDigits  // "0856"
```

Comment: This approach scales poorly as the number of digits gets larger.

Comment: @RobNapier the OP is asking for a four digits. In my tests here it generates around 90 numbers to extract 45. But there is no bias with 0 first here

Comment: Yeah; I can't figure out why it biases towards a leading zero when n is larger. My first calculations on it suggest it shouldn't, but I never seen a non-zero-leading result with n=8 or n=9.

Comment: There's no need for the intermediate `Array` BTW. You can build a `Set` from any `SequenceType`.

Comment: By "n=8 or n=9" I mean "looking for an 8-digit or 9-digit number." A good algorithm here shouldn't be tied to exactly four digits if it can help it. On StackOverflow, people tend to re-use these answers for similar problems that may not be identical.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Code** - For Generation of 4 digit

It gives number between 1000 and 9999.

```
    func random() -> String {
    var result = ""
    repeat {
        result = String(format:"%04d", arc4random_uniform(10000) )
    } while result.count < 4 || Int(result)! < 1000
    print(result)
    return result    
}
```

**Please Note** - You can remove this **Int(result)! < 1000** if you want numbers like this - 0123, 0913