# Swift 2 How to create a random dictionary from 2 similar arrays

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift2, xcode7

I'm using xcode 7, and I am wondering how to create a randomized dictionary from two similar arrays.
For example

```
var array1 = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "strawberry", "cherry"]
var array2 = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "strawberry", "cherry"]
```

I then want the code to create a random dictionary like so:

```
var dict = ["apple": "banana", "banana": "apple", "orange": "cherry", "strawberry": "orange", "cherry": "strawberry"]
```

Also, I don't want to have both value and key to be the same, ie no "apple": "apple".

I'm relatively new to coding.  Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your particular example is a bit contrived as there is really no point in dealing with two identical arrays, you can simply use one. I guess something like this should do the trick:

```
var fruits = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "strawberry", "cherry"]
var dict = [String: String]()

for (keyIndex, key) in fruits.enumerate() {
    var valueIndex: Int {
        var index: Int
        repeat {
            index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(fruits.count)))
        } while index == keyIndex || dict.values.contains(fruits[index])
        return index
    }
    dict[key] = fruits[valueIndex]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, and helping me get rid of some redundancy.  One thing, though.  I was hoping it would use every string in the array once for a key, and once for an index.  With this code, it's using every string once for a key, but maybe multiple times for and index.

Comment: Just make an additional check in the while statement: `while index == keyIndex || dict.values.contains(fruits[index])`

Comment: Thank you very much.  This works perfectly.  I really appreciate it.  Hopefully these things kind of things will come easily to me in time

Comment: Your welcome, and I'm sure it will. The more you code the easier it becomes. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `shuffle` function from [Nate Cook's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24029847/746347) to shuffle `values` array and then simply fill dictionary with keys and values:

```
var keys = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "strawberry", "cherry"]
var values = keys

values.shuffle()

var d = [String: String]()

for (index, item) in keys.enumerate() {
    d[item] = values[index]
}
```

The advantage of this solution that it's O(n) (execution time and consumed memory linearly depends from number of items).