# Sorting an array of images

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimageview, arc4random

I'm programming a game in swift and i want to create a code that let me sort a group of image in every x seconds. It's 5 images, and the idea is that in every 2 seconds, the position of the images will be changed and cannot have repeated images.

[image]

So will have a lot of combinations:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5

5, 4, 3, 2, 1

1, 3, 2, 5, 4

etc...

Above is the code that i made, but i thinks this is not the best way to do that.

var timer: NSTimer!

```
func startTimer() {
    if timer != nil {
        timer.invalidate()
    }

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "sortImg", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

// imagens de elementos de alimentação
@IBOutlet weak var imgCoracao: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imgCoxinha: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imgSerie: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imgSushi: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imgTod: UIImageView!

func sortImg() {
    let rand = arc4random_uniform(4)

    if rand == 0 {
        imgCoracao.image = UIImage(named: "icon_coxinha.png")
        imgCoxinha.image = UIImage(named: "icon_toddy.png")
        imgSerie.image = UIImage(named: "icon_sushi.png")
        imgSushi.image = UIImage(named: "icon_serie.png")
        imgTod.image = UIImage(named: "icon_coracao.png")

    } else if rand == 1 {
        imgCoracao.image = UIImage(named: "icon_coxinha.png")
        imgCoxinha.image = UIImage(named: "icon_sushi.png")
        imgSerie.image = UIImage(named: "icon_toddy.png")
        imgSushi.image = UIImage(named: "icon_coracao.png")
        imgTod.image = UIImage(named: "icon_serie.png")
    } else if rand == 2 {
        imgCoracao.image = UIImage(named: "icon_serie.png")
        imgCoxinha.image = UIImage(named: "icon_coracao.png")
        imgSerie.image = UIImage(named: "icon_sushi.png")
        imgSushi.image = UIImage(named: "icon_toddy.png")
        imgTod.image = UIImage(named: "icon_coxinha.png")
    }


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    startTimer()
    sortImg()
}
```

what the best way to do that? I tried to implement a function with arc4random_uniform and If Else statements, but i cant cover all the possibilities manually. And i don't know how to implement the time factor to make trigger the change.

Comment: What's the best way to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34465269/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus i edit the post with my code. I wasn't trying to take someone to make my code. Sorry if i pass this impression. I'm just seeking the best way to do what i said.

Comment: the problem that i'm having is that the solution that i found it's too laborious to implement and don't cover all the possibilities. The code that i posted here in stackflow is what i've done.

Comment: You should store names of images in array and compute all permutations of this array. Then just iterate through them. You can also shuffle those permutations a bit to make order of them random.

Comment: @ZéMoreira try let shuffledImages = [img1,img2,img3,img4,img5].sort { (a, b) -> Bool in arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 }

Comment: @LeoDabus but how i add this array of images to the UIImageViews?

Comment: @ZéMoreira shuffledImages[0], shuffledImages[1] up to shuffledImages[4]

Comment: i did that, but some images keep showing twice. I want one image of each in each UIImageView.

Comment: nevermind. it was my mistake. Can you add your answer as a comment so i can mark?