# One-liner to generate Powerball picks in Swift?

Tags: ruby, swift

With the U.S.'s large $1.5 Billion lottery this week, I wrote a function in Ruby to make Powerball picks.  In [Powerball](https://www.powerball.com), you choose 5 numbers from the range `1..69` (with no duplicates) and 1 number from the range `1..26`.

This is what I came up with:

```
def pball
    Array(1..69).shuffle[0..4].sort + [rand(1..26)]
end
```

It works by creating an array of integers from 1 to 69, shuffling that array, choosing the first 5 numbers, sorting those, and finally adding on a number from 1 to 26.

To do this in Swift takes a bit more work since Swift doesn't have the built-in `shuffle` method on `Array`.

This was my attempt:

```
func pball() -> [Int] {
    let arr = Array(1...69).map{($0, drand48())}.sort{$0.1 < $1.1}.map{$0.0}[0...4].sort()
    return arr + [Int(arc4random_uniform(26) + 1)]
}
```

Since there is no `shuffle` method, it works by creating an `[Int]` with values in the range `1...69`.  It then uses `map` to create `[(Int, Double)]`, an array of tuple pairs that contain the numbers and a random `Double` in the range `0.0 ..< 1.0`.  It then sorts this array using the `Double` values and uses a second `map` to return to `[Int]` and then uses the slice `[0...4]` to extract the first 5 numbers and `sort()` to sort them.

In the second line, it appends a number in the range `1...26`.  I tried adding this to the first line, but Swift gave the error:

> Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider
> breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions.

Can anyone suggest how to turn this into a 1-line function?  Perhaps there is a better way to choose the 5 numbers from `1...69`.

Comment: Is is random? I get most of the time (the first time I call it) [7, 12, 30, 55, 58, x]

Comment: Good question, @LeoDabus. I'd assumed that is just the Playground being funny.

Comment: I've heard about drand48 seeding first. Can that be it?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to just use `arc4random()` to avoid having to seed the random function.

Comment: An easier way in Ruby is to use [Array#sample](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample): `[*1..69].sample(5) << (1+rand(26)) #=> [24, 3, 61, 67, 22, 10]`.

Comment: Various array shuffling methods are given here: [How do I shuffle an array in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift).

Comment: ... and using `shuffle()` from the accepted answer, `Array(1...69).shuffle()[0...4].sort() + [Int(arc4random_uniform(26) + 1)]` does compile.

Comment: "Expression too complex" not very useful compiler feedback is filed as rdar://24217037

Comment: @bbum, Swift's compiler errors tend to be extremely **un**helpful. I hope the LLVM team goes back and does a major push to improve them soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Xcode 10 • Swift 4.2**

Swift now has added [`shuffled()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange/2995050-shuffled) to `ClosedRange` and [`random(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2995646-random) to `Int` which now makes this easily accomplished in one line:

```
func pball() -> [Int] {
    return (1...69).shuffled().prefix(5).sorted() + [Int.random(in: 1...26)]
}
```

**Further trimmings:**

Because of the return type of `pball()`, the `Int` can be inferred in the `random` method call.  Also, `.prefix(5)` can be replaced with `[...4]`.  Finally, `return` can be omitted from the one-line function:

```
func pball() -> [Int] {
    (1...69).shuffled()[...4].sorted() + [.random(in: 1...26)]
}
```

Comment: The usefulness of the new random features are really shown in problems such as this one (comparing with my quite complex pre-Swift 4 answer), nice!

Answer (score 6):

**Xcode 8.3 • Swift 3.1**

```
import GameKit 

var powerballNumbers: [Int] {
    return (GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjects(in: Array(1...69)) as! [Int])[0..<5].sorted() + [Int(arc4random_uniform(26) + 1)]
}

powerballNumbers   // [5, 9, 62, 65, 69, 2]
```

---

**Swift 2.x**

```
import GameKit 

var powerballNumbers: [Int] {
    return (GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(Array(1...69)) as! [Int])[0...4].sort() + [Int(arc4random_uniform(26).successor())]
}

powerballNumbers   // [21, 37, 39, 42, 65, 23]
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't find the "one-liner" concept very compelling. Some languages lend themselves to it; others don't. I would suggest giving Swift a `shuffle` method to start with:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func shuffle () {
        for var i = self.count - 1; i != 0; i-- {
            let ix1 = i
            let ix2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(i+1)))
            (self[ix1], self[ix2]) = (self[ix2], self[ix1])
        }
    }
}
```

But since I made this `mutating`, we still need more than one line to express the entire operation because we have to have a `var` reference to our starting array:

```
var arr = Array(1...69)
(1...4).forEach {_ in arr.shuffle()}
let result = Array(arr[0..<5]) + [Int(arc4random_uniform(26)) + 1]
```

If you really insist on the one-liner, and you don't count the code needed to implement `shuffle`, then you can do it, though less efficiently, by defining `shuffle` more like this:

```
extension Array {
    func shuffle () -> [Element] {
        var arr = self
        for var i = arr.count - 1; i != 0; i-- {
            let ix1 = i
            let ix2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(i+1)))
            (arr[ix1], arr[ix2]) = (arr[ix2], arr[ix1])
        }
        return arr
    }
}
```

And here's your one-liner:

```
let result = Array(1...69).shuffle().shuffle().shuffle().shuffle()[0..<5] + [Int(arc4random_uniform(26)) + 1]
```

But oops, I omitted your sort. I don't see how to do that without getting the "too complex" error; to work around that, I had to split it into two lines:

```
var result = Array(1...69).shuffle().shuffle().shuffle().shuffle()[0..<5].sort(<)
result.append(Int(arc4random_uniform(26)) + 1)
```

Comment: I understand your feelings on the "one-liner" concept.  In this case, it is more of an academic exercise to see what can be done vs. what should be done.

Comment: @vacawama I modified my answer so that _after_ defining `shuffle` you _do_ get a one-liner. But I don't like it. :)

Comment: That for var loop will be removed in Swift 3.0 https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md

Comment: @LeoDabus Yeah, I know, I'm not looking forward to that. Or the loss of C-type for loops. Or much of anything. :(

Comment: Now, from the other side of the Swift 3 transition I don't miss the `for (;;)` all that much. `for (index, element) in array.enumerated()` gives the same ability to iterate through array entries with an index. Granted things like making a Fibonacci sequence generator with a C-style for loop, or counting backwards by 3s aren't as easy, but how often do you really need to do those things? (And if you write a Fibonacci generator as a C `for(;;)` loop outside of a test question you should be shot anyway...)

Comment: @DuncanC Actually those things are very easy indeed, and elegant too, and efficient, thanks to the new `sequence` global function.

Comment: @DuncanC see e.g. [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203182/fibonacci-numbers-generator-in-swift-3) for examples of the use cases mentioned by matt (global `sequence` function).

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
let winningDraw = (1...69).sort{ _ in arc4random_uniform(2) > 0}[0...4].sort() + [Int(arc4random_uniform(26)+1)]
```

[edit] above formula wasn't random.  but this one will be

```
(1...69).map({Int(rand()%1000*70+$0)}).sort().map({$0%70})[0...4].sort() + [Int(rand()%26+1)]
```

Comment: @Alain T. this is not true random as it will tend to pick number 2 like 20% of the draws and it will never pick number 1

Comment: You are right, the internal algorithm for the sort() function is probably a variant of Knut's quick sort so it will have a tendency to spread the distribution toward the edges (low and high values) of the number list.   My bad.

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of it, a non-`GameplayKit` (long) one-liner for Swift 3, using the global [`sequence(state:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2011998-sequence) function to generate random elements from the mutable `state` array rather than shuffling the array (although mutating the value array 5 times, so some extra copy operations here...)

```
let powerballNumbers = Array(sequence(state: Array(1...69), next: { 
    (s: inout [Int]) -> Int? in s.remove(at: Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(s.count))))})
    .prefix(5).sorted()) + [Int(arc4random_uniform(26) + 1)]
```

... broken down for readability.

---

*(Possible in future Swift version)*

If the [type inference weren't broken `inout` closure parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201844/global-function-sequencestatenext-and-type-inference) (as arguments to closures), we could reduce the above to:

```
let powerballNumbers = Array(sequence(state: Array(1...69), next: {
    $0.remove(at: Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32($0.count)))) })
    .prefix(5).sorted()) + [Int(arc4random_uniform(26) + 1)]
```

If we'd also allow the following extension

```
extension Int {
    var rand: Int { return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(exactly: self) ?? 0)) }
}
```

Then, we could go on to reduce the one-line to:

```
let powerballNumbers = Array(sequence(state: Array(1...69), next: { $0.remove(at: $0.count.rand) }).prefix(5).sorted()) + [26.rand + 1]
```

Comment: Just curious, @dfri.  What drew your attention to this nearly year-old question?

Comment: @vacawama I randomly visited your profile via your comment [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409543/) (which I commented to as well) and the top item of _"Newest questions"_ on your profile (namely; this one) caught my attention :)

Comment: The funny thing is that I was revisiting this question myself at the very time you answered.  I wondered if somehow I had triggered the question to appear in some active list on SO.

Comment: @vacawama Not in this case, seemingly rather some random funny synchronicity!

Comment: Yeah. Coincidence is sometimes very funny/creepy!

Comment: I've accepted this *crazy-good* answer.  Why is the closure returning `Int?` instead of `Int`

Comment: @vacawama it's too bad `sequence(state:next:)` don't yet accept a closure as the `state` (`inout` closure) due to [a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3450), otherwise we could go really crazy with this function :) As to the optional return: the closure `next` must be allowed to return `nil`, in which case the sequence is terminated (as specified in the function signature for `sequence(state:next)`; `next: @escaping (inout State) -> T?`). This fact is never used here, however, as we simply prefix an never-terminated (or, runtime-crashing at 70th element) sequence for its `5` first members.

Comment: FWIW, I was able to remove the `?` and it still works.  Is that just Swift not enforcing the requirement of `next` returning an optional?

Comment: @vacawama thanks for the info, that's peculiar (and surprising), since it means we may never terminate the sequence "internally" (e.g. above, we would like to add a `guard !s.isEmpty else { return nil }` prior to the return for runtime safety; not an issue here as the `prefix` number is not larger than the size of the initial `state` array).

Comment: @vacawama I didn't know what you pointed out was possible, but it seems as if a closure with an optional return type accepts the "subset" type of same arguments but non-optional return type, much like an optional argument to some method accepts non-optionals ([gist](https://gist.github.com/dfrib/0ba54dd987fd9dc01ece63926576d812)). Although I don't find this as intuitive as for the "regular" argument case (since it isn't the full closure that's optional, just its return type), I guess we can assume its intended behaviour?