# How to check/predicate function type in Swift?

Tags: swift, types, functional-programming, swift3, occurrence-typing

For example:

```
func f(x: Int) -> Int {
    return x
}


func h(f: @escaping (Int) -> Any) {
    if (f is (Int) -> Int) {
        print(f(1))
    } else {
        print("invalid")
    }
}


h(f: f)
```

I expect it to print out `1` but it actually prints out `invalid`.

Comment: A kludgey way:  `if f(1) is Int {`

Comment: I suspect the type of the instance "wrapped" by `Any` in the supplied closure `f` cannot be inferred by the compiler without actually calling `f`. In the eye of the compiler, `f` is a closure on the form `{ arg in; /* ... */; return someInstanceOfTypeAny }`. Whether `someInstanceOfTypeAny` is in fact of type `Int` or not can only be ascertained by actually studying the type of _an actual instance returned by the closure `f`_, e.g. as @vacawama suggests above. The answer below use a template workaround where `T` is actually a _concrete type_ (not a runtime wrapper!) for each call to `h`.

Comment: @dfri When passing `f` to `h`, compiler knows the type of `f` is `(Int) -> Int`, I wonder why it cannot narrow `(Int) -> Any` to sub type `(Int) -> Int`? `f` is not an anonymous closure without type annotation. `f` is well annotated.

Comment: @weakish `Any` here is not a typeholder (that holds any type that _conforms_ to `Any`) in the same way the generic typeholder `T` is used in the answers below. If you try out your example substituting `Any` with a custom class `Base` and return type of `func f (...` with `Derived` (which derives from `Base`), and test the supplied closure to be `(Int) -> Derived`, you'll see that you will still enter the `"invalid"` body when supplying an `(Int) -> Derived` closure to the `h`, as the parameter `f` in `h` is explicitly type annotated as `(Int) -> Base` (even if `(Int) -> Derived` is supplied).

Answer (score 3):

There's a workaround using generics:

```
func intF(x: Int) -> Int {
    return x
}

func stringF(x: Int) -> String {
    return "\(x)"
}

func h<T>(f: (Int) -> T) {
    if (T.self == Int.self) {
        print(f(1))
    } else {
        print("invalid")
    }
}

h(f: intF)    // prints: 1
h(f: stringF) // prints: invalid
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Any` is almost always a sign of code smell, you should try to rely as much as possible of the type safety that Swift provides. You can achieve this by making `h` generic, thus verifiable at compile time.

```
// the overload that does the actual stuff
func h(f: @escaping (Int) -> Int) {
    print(f(1))
}

// this maps to all other types
func h<T>(f: @escaping (Int) -> T) {
    print("invalid")
}

h { _ in return "15" }  // Invalid
h {  2 * $0 }           // 2
```

Heck, you could even give up the generic overload, thus you'll have for free compile checks instead of runtime failures (much, much reliable and predictive)

Comment: I wrote `Any` so `(Int) -> Int` is a sub type of `(Int) -> Any`. This is to make the code example short, without defining a lot of classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite `h` into a generic function:

```
func h<T>(f: @escaping (Int) -> T) {        
    if T.self == Int.self  {
        print(f(1))
    } else {
        print("invalid")
    }
}
```

But the better way to to write type-specific overloads for `h` and a generic catch-all for the rest (if you need it at all).

Comment: Is this the same as @nils answer?