# Display a certain number of questions randomly from a pList file

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I am creating a simple Quiz app. I stored a total of 300 questions in a pList file and displayed the questions one by one RANDOMLY.

Now, how do you get only a CERTAIN NUMBER of questions from the said pList file? For instance, in my 300-questions pList file, I am using all of the questions in one "go". However, there is some kind of a "practice mode" where I only need to get 100 questions RANDOMLY out of the 300-question pList file. How do I do that?

I have seen some resources but they're all in Objective-C.

Comment: Please include your code so we can see where you are at with this problem and so that we may be able to more clearly instruct you.

Comment: Just shuffle your array and get an array slice prefix(n)

Comment: @LeoDabus how do I use the "array slice prefix(n)" ?

Comment: `["abc","def","ghi","jkl"].prefix(2)`

Comment: @LeoDabus I shuffle my arrays using an extension questionArray.shuffle(), how do you implement the prefix(n)? sorry I don't quite understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nate Cook's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59541/nate-cook) shuffle extension from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24029847/2303865) to shuffle your array and pick as many elements as you need from your array using array's prefix(n) method:

```
extension Array {
    var shuffled: [Element] {
        guard count > 1 else { return self }
        var elements = self
        for index in indices {
            let newIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(elements.count - index))) + index
             guard index != newIndex else { continue }
            swap(&elements[index], &elements[newIndex])
        }
        return elements
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
let questions = Array(1...300).map{"Question \($0)"}
let shuffledQuestions = questions.shuffled
let firstOneHundred = shuffledQuestions.prefix(100)   // ["Question 163", "Question 77", "Question 262", "Question 292", "Question 229", "Question 199", "Question 93", "Question 35", "Question 19", "Question 65", "Question 107", "Question 142", "Question 174", "Question 172", "Question 240", "Question 131", "Question 274", "Question 252", "Question 214", "Question 285", "Question 185", "Question 219", "Question 51", "Question 267", "Question 170", "Question 6", "Question 55", "Question 67", "Question 115", "Question 148", "Question 137", "Question 139", "Question 116", "Question 259", "Question 24", "Question 283", "Question 273", "Question 147", "Question 17", "Question 16", "Question 97", "Question 2", "Question 74", "Question 215", "Question 184", "Question 84", "Question 247", "Question 73", "Question 37", "Question 7", "Question 226", "Question 1", "Question 173", "Question 238", "Question 46", "Question 108", "Question 114", "Question 119", "Question 251", "Question 197", "Question 159", "Question 72", "Question 70", "Question 150", "Question 289", "Question 143", "Question 141", "Question 47", "Question 69", "Question 88", "Question 244", "Question 189", "Question 129", "Question 266", "Question 221", "Question 248", "Question 92", "Question 236", "Question 33", "Question 175", "Question 133", "Question 210", "Question 228", "Question 213", "Question 64", "Question 223", "Question 198", "Question 202", "Question 68", "Question 291", "Question 230", "Question 270", "Question 103", "Question 83", "Question 271", "Question 62", "Question 109", "Question 121", "Question 10", "Question 232"]
```