# How to put variable inside text field AND how to convert all elements to string NOT just 1 at a time?

Tags: ios, iphone, string, swift, swift2

This is a follow up question to [How to have 10 characters total and make sure at least one character from 4 different sets is used randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36931474/how-to-have-10-characters-total-and-make-sure-at-least-one-character-from-4-diff/36931867#36931867)

this is my code so far

```
let sets = ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "1234567890", "\"-/:;()$&@.,?!'[]{}#%^\\|~<>€£¥•.,"].map { Array($0.characters) }

var randoms = sets.map { $0.random }

while randoms.count < 10 {
  randoms.append(sets.random.random)
}

var convertedElems = String()

let something = randoms.shuffled()

for key in something {
  convertedElems = String(key)
}

uniqueRoomID.text = randoms.shuffled()
```

Im getting an error saying cannot convert [Element] to type "String"

So i tried a for loop but that only converts 1 at a time when its supposed to do all 10

my other question is i tried storing a character in a variable and then setting a text field.text equal to that variable and nothing happened

What am i doing wrong here

Comment: You're getting this error because you did not copied the extensions.

Comment: i did copy the extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `randoms.shuffled()` is an array of `Character`s.  You need to convert it back into a `String`.

Change this:

```
uniqueRoomID.text = randoms.shuffled()
```

to this:

```
uniqueRoomID.text = String(randoms.shuffled())
```