# nested for-loops on an array

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit

I'm using `SpriteKit` and `Swift 3` to create a simple game.
I have an array of Rings/Circles:

```
mRings = [mRingOne, mRingTwo, mRingThree, mRingFour, mRingFive]
```

each object in the array has a different color, In some point in the game I want to change the color of each ring, but I have 2 condition for this to happen:
1. a ring should not have the color it had one iteration before.
2. each ring should be in a different color from the others.

for the first condition I did this:

```
func changeRingsColor(){
    var previousColor: UIColor?
    for ring in mRings {
        previousColor = ring.fillColor
        repeat{
            ring.fillColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: mColors[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(5)))])
        }while(ring.fillColor.isEqual(previousColor))
    }
}
```

and it is working, however, I couldn't figure out a way to answer the second condition.
In `Java` I would probably do something like this:

```
    for (int i=0; i<mRings.length; i++){
      for( int j=1; j<mRings.length; j++){
        if (ring[i].fillColor == ring[j].fillColor){
            generate another color for 'j' ring.
        }
    }
 }
```

but nothing I tried worked.
Hope you guys can help me, Thanks in advance!

btw, `mColors` is an array of 5 different colors, from there I pick the colors.

Comment: What you might be looking for is a "random derangement", i.e. a random permutation which changes every element.

Comment: The simplest algorithm is to generate a random order of elements and then pass the colors to the next element in that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to ignore some of the implementation details and focus on the core of the question, which is:

- Loop through an array
- Within each loop, start a new loop at the current index to the end of the array.

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding the above. But I would do it like this:

```
for (index, ring) in mRings.enumerated() {
    let remainingRings = mRings[index+1..<mRings.count]
    for otherRing in remainingRings {
        print("Now comparing \(ring) to \(otherRing)")
    }
}
```

First, `enumerated()` gives you both the current ring, and the index, on each iteration of the first for loop. Then, we slice the array from the current index to the end (`remainingRings`), and loop through those.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `let remainingRings = mRings[index+1..<mRings.count]` ??

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to rewrite Java code in this way :

```
let mRings = ["mRingOne", "mRingTwo", "mRingThree", "mRingFour", "mRingFive"]

for (index, item) in mRings.enumerated() {
    for item in index + 1..<mRings.count {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
func changeRingsColor(){
    // extract the previous colors
    let colors = rings.map { $0.fillColor }
    // the order in which the rings will pass color to each other
    let passOrder = mRings.indices.shuffled()

    for i in mRings.indices {
        let previous = i == 0 ? mRings.count - 1 : i - 1        
        mRings[passOrder[i]].fillColor = colors[passOrder[previous]]
    }
}
```

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24029847/669586) implementation of `shuffled`

How does it work?

Instead of randomly choosing a color for each individual ring, I am randomly generating an order in which the rings will swap the colors (`passOrder`). Since every ring will pass its color to a different ring in that order, you can be sure no color will stay the same.

Comment: That is an interesting approach to get a random "derangement" (permutation without fixed point). However, it will not produce *all possible* derangements. For example, ABCD will never be permuted to BADC. (No criticism, just a remark.)

Comment: @MartinR Very true, for 4 items there is exactly 1 permutation that is missed :) I wanted to illustrate the point that the algorithm shouldn't be done for every element separately.

Comment: All permutations with more than one cycle are missing, for 4 items that should be BADC, CDAB, DCBA unless I am mistaken. – But this is going off-topic now :)

Comment: @MartinR Oh yes, I forgot that a cycle with 3 items is also possible if the last item is not identity. I will have to calculate if this algorithm does not remove too many options.