# fatal error: swapping a location with itself is not supported with Swift 3.0.1 and Xcode 8.1.2

Tags: swift, xcode8

I have a look at the answers in regard to Swift2.0.1 in the website of stackoverflow. In spite of the usage of arc4random_uniform() , but it still could not be solved. Please help look at the lines of code as follows.

```
extension Array {
    mutating func shuffle() {
            for first in stride(from: self.count - 1, through: 1, by: -1) {
            let second = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(first + 1)))
                      swap(&self[first], &self[second])
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Working shuffle code for all Swift versions can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24029847/1187415.

Comment: After reviewing the similar issue again in Swift 2.0.1 in the website, I add the check line  "if first != second { }", it works now. It seems that logic induction is correct. Thanks for the reminding.

Comment: Martin, thanks for your direction. After I correct it, I go to the weblinks that you mentioned. It is a similar question exactly but have a lot of subtle answers.  That will be quite helpful for an in-depth understanding for variant scenarios.