# How do I randomize table view cells in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, random, xcode8

Say I have 5 cells that I created in a table view that have names in them. How would I randomize them after tapping a button and put them in a different order?

Comment: Your button would shuffle the array populating the table view, and you would reload the tableview

Comment: Here is how to shuffle your array: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24026510/1630618

Answer (score 2):

Here is some pseudo code:

```
func randomize()
  {
    randomize order of the arrayThatFillsTableView
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

To shuffle your array that fills the tableview, use the following extension:

```
extension Array
{
    mutating func shuffle()
    {
        for _ in 0..<10
        {
            sort { (_,_) in arc4random() < arc4random() }
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, simply do: `arrayThatFillsTableView.shuffle()`

The final product is this:

```
func randomize()
  {
    arrayThatFillsTableView.shuffle()
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

Simply call `randomize()` whenever you need to shuffle.
Keep in mind that extensions go outside of class declarations.

Comment: I know I have to reload the tableView's data, I'm just stuck on the actual randomizing. My app allows you to add a name and it will populate a cell. I want to be able to randomize those names.

Comment: then your question is wrong. it should be "how to randomize a String"

Comment: @muescha presumably, his question is correct if he stores those names within an array, the end result is the same.

Comment: How would I go about randomizing the cells then?

Comment: This randomizes the array that fills the table, then just reload the data.

Comment: So i am actually using core data, and I'm pretty sure I have to randomize my fetchedObjects, except I can't add the `shuffle()` function to that array because the array is immutable.