# How to generate random string form array of elements by compared with another array of elements in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I aware to get random character from a string. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45538903/6479530) is the code,

```
func randomString(_ length: Int) -> String {

    let master = Array("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_123456789".characters) //0...62 = 63
    var randomString = ""

    for _ in 1...length{

        let random = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(master.count))
        randomString.append(String(master[Int(random)]))
    }
    return randomString
}
```

**Usage :**

```
var randomArray1 = [String]()

for _ in 0...62{

   randomArray1.append(self.randomString(1))
}
```

Here, If `randomArray1.append(self.randomString(x))`, then `x = 1...N`

**Checking repeated elements :**

```
var sameElementCatcher = [String]()

for x in 0...62{

    let element = randomArray1[x]
    randomArray1[x] = ""
    if randomArray1.contains(element){
        sameElementCatcher.append(element)
    }
}

print("Same Elements")
print(sameElementCatcher.count != 0 ? sameElementCatcher : "Array count is zero")
```

**Output:**

> Same Elements
>
> ["_", "u", "8", "7", "E", "P", "u", "y", "C", "-", "C", "x", "l", "j",
>   "t", "D", "U", "2", "e", "2"]

But I need to get array of 62 unique random characters from `master` by compared with `randomArray1`. i.e., Array count is zero

How can I achieve this without delay?

**Note:**

Also, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift) post also I have a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45540740/6479530) for shuffling array. But this post different from shuffling only, Please, see `usage`.

Comment: Are you sure that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift does not solve your problem? Isn't `master.characters.shuffled()` what you need?

Comment: @MartinR , Yes bro is not `master.characters.shuffled()`. I need to generate random keys like firebase.  `randomArray1.append(self.randomString(1))` is just example. I can use `randomArray1.append(self.randomString(6))` also.

Comment: Summarizing. You need to generate a random text where all the characters are unique?

Comment: `import GameKit` and  `let randomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: master.count)`
        
        `return master[randomNumber].description` for random string try this may it helps

Comment: @MidhunKMohan , Okay bro I will try and let you know

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski , Yes bro, sry,,, I need to create particular length random text from master. Once I generate text from random characters then I am appending it to new array. For example, master has 63 char length. so I can generate 63 unique random keys with length of 1. But I am not able to do like that. Final array had lot of repeated chars. I need unique element in final array with this logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try like this?
What I understand from your question. `generate a random text where all the characters are unique`.
Before appending your random string to your array check is array have that `char` then append into your array.

```
func randomString(_ length: Int) -> String {
let master = Array("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_123456789".characters) //0...62 = 63
var randomString = ""

for _ in 1...length{

    let random = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(master.count))
    randomString.append(String(master[Int(random)]))
}
return randomString
}

var randomArray1 = [String]()
var tempRandomString = ""
let totalRandomCount = 62
var randomArrayCount = 0

while (totalRandomCount > randomArrayCount) {
    tempRandomString = randomString(1)
    if !randomArray1.contains(tempRandomString) {
        randomArray1.append(tempRandomString)
        randomArrayCount+=1
    }
}
print(randomArray1)
```

Output: `["X", "u", "j", "1", "n", "E", "D", "q", "U", "6", "T", "O", "f", "J", "i", "c", "W", "V", "G", "R", "k", "7", "_", "8", "-", "l", "w", "4", "e", "Q", "C", "m", "M", "Y", "o", "S", "B", "2", "Z", "P", "p", "N", "y", "H", "a", "h", "z", "s", "b", "A", "3", "g", "x", "L", "v", "F", "d", "r", "t", "K", "9", "5"]`

I tried this with playground. For this output `199` times loop executed.

If anyone knows better than this update yours.

Comment: Yes you are right. generate unique random text. Thanks for the effort. friend :)

Comment: Thanks bro I got key from your answer :)

Comment: Happy to help. If you didn't use this completely this method, share your answer.