# How can I perform SORT_BY or ORDER_BY random in iOS core data?

Tags: ios

How can I perform SORT_BY or ORDER_BY random in iOS core data?

need to fetch 10 random records which counter is greater than 10. *counter is an attribute

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You may get more helpful advice if you explain what it is you actually want rather than how you think you need to do it. Core Data isn't built to do what you're asking.

Comment: need to fetch 10 random records which counter is greater than 10. *counter is an attribute

Answer (score 2):

This isn't supported directly by core data, but you could do something like the following (depending on how many rows you have in your data set).

For a smallish number (in the thousands), you can fetch all managed object IDs (setting the fetch result type of your fetch request to the appropriate value) that match your predicate. This will give you a low-overhead array from which you can then randomly select 10 IDs and then fetch the full objects.

For a larger number of rows, first obtain the count of the fetch request for all matching objects, then generate a random number between 0 and the count, then use that as the fetch offset, limiting your fetch request to one result. Repeat for as many random records as you need.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, you cannot randomly "sort" or order straight from CoreData. It requires a key within the object which won't be random.

I would instead advise that you fetch the objects you want, put them into a (mutable) array and then shuffle them yourself. There are many different shuffling algorithms online, and I'll point you towards this link which was at the top of Google for me: [Shuffling an Array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift)

Comment: Thank, But my problem is array is too big. Fetching is taking time. How can I reduce that?

Comment: Thats a tough one, have you thought about randomly selecting a range of your data, and then shuffling it? You can use a mixture of `fetchLimit` and `fetchOffset`. It wont be random, but it might be a starting point?

Comment: I tried this way already. Not helpful. Is there any other way?

Comment: Im afraid Im not aware of any other ways. Hopefully someone else may be able to give a better answer. Sorry

Comment: Thanks for your help, :(

Comment: @DeepakKumarSahu - what is *"Not helpful"* about using `fetchLimit` and `fetchOffset`?

Comment: @DonMag fetchOffset won't shuffle and fetchLimit isn't the solution. If it does please tell me how to do. Thanks

Comment: @DeepakKumarSahu - The 2nd part of the answer from **jrturton** (*For a larger number of rows...*) is what you need.