# Quiz app to pick questions from 8 group of questions randomly?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I build an application for iOS and I want it to pick questions from 8 different groups of questions and randomly. The number of questions is 356 and only 50 of them must be picked randomly.

1. 8 questions from 1st group
2. 5 questions from 2nd group
3. 5 questions from 3rd group
4. 6 questions from 4th group
5. 6 questions from 5th group
6. 5 questions from 6th group
7. 9 questions from 7th group
8. 6 questions from 8th group

**Total: 50 questions.**

What i did is that, i build the quiz, but it reads all the questions and shows them to the user. The questions are read from a .json file.

**Here is my code:**
(Because there are no comments on the code, ask me.)

```
import UIKit

struct Question {
    var Question: String!
    var Answers: [String]!
    var Answer: Int!

    init(item: [String: Any])
    {
        self.Question = item["Question"] as? String
        self.Answers = item["Answers"] as? [String]
        self.Answer = item["Answer"] as? Int
    }
} 

class LittleTestViewController: UIViewController {

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!

    var Questions = [Question]()
    var QNumber = Int()
    var answerNumber = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        jsonParsingQuestionsFile()
        pickQuestion()
    }

    func jsonParsingQuestionsFile ()
    {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json"),
            let array = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe), options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)) as? [[String : Any]] else{
                return
        }
        for item in array
        {
            self.Questions.append(Question(item: item))
        }
    }

    func pickQuestion ()
    {
        if Questions.count > 0 {
            QNumber = 0
            questionLabel.text = Questions[QNumber].Question

            answerNumber = Questions[QNumber].Answer

            for i in 0..<buttons.count{
                buttons[i].setTitle(Questions[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
            Questions.remove(at: QNumber)
        }
        else
        {
           print ("End")
        }
    }

@IBAction func btn1(_ sender: UIButton){
        Unhide()
        if answerNumber == 0 {
            print ("Correct!!")
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    @IBAction func btn2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Unhide()
        if answerNumber == 1 {
           print ("Correct!!")
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    @IBAction func btn3(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Unhide()
        if answerNumber == 2 {
            print ("Correct!!")
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    @IBAction func btn4(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Unhide()
        if answerNumber == 3 {
            print ("Correct!!")
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**data.json**

```
[ {"Question":"Group 1. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 2},
  {"Question":"Group 1. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 2},
  {"Question":"Group 1. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 3},
  {"Question":"Group 2. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 2},
  {"Question":"Group 2. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 1},
  {"Question":"Group 2. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 2},
  {"Question":"Group 3. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 2},
  {"Question":"Group 3. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 2},
  {"Question":"Group 4. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 2},
  {"Question":"Group 4. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 3},
  {"Question":"Group 4. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 2},
  {"Question":"Group 5. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 0},
  {"Question":"Group 5. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 2},
  {"Question":"Group 6. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 0},
  {"Question":"Group 7. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 2},
  {"Question":"Group 8. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 0},
  {"Question":"Group 8. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 1},
  {"Question":"Group 9. lalala?", "Answers":["lala","trtr","asas","bbbb"],"Answer": 2},]
```

This .json file is just an example there are more questions for every group. Every group has about 45 questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the advices guys. But I found the way on how to do it. I only changed the pickQuestion function.

```
 func pickQuestion ()
{
    if Questions.count > 0 && questionscount < 8{
        QNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("KEK")}.count)))
        questionscount += 1
        questionLabel.text = Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("KEK")}[QNumber].Question

        self.title = "Ερώτηση: \(Int(questionscount))/50"
        answerNumber = Questions[QNumber].Answer

        for i in 0..<buttons.count{
            buttons[i].setTitle(Questions[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        print(QNumber)
        Questions.remove(at: QNumber)

    }else if Questions.count > 0 && questionscount < 13{

        QNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("M")}.count)))
        questionscount += 1
        questionLabel.text = Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("M")}[QNumber].Question

        self.title = "Ερώτηση: \(Int(questionscount))/50"
        answerNumber = Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("M")}[QNumber].Answer


        for i in 0..<buttons.count{
            buttons[i].setTitle(Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("M")}[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        print(QNumber)
        Questions.remove(at: QNumber)

    }else if Questions.count > 0 && questionscount < 18{
        QNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("N")}.count)))
        questionscount += 1
        questionLabel.text = Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("N")}[QNumber].Question


        self.title = "Ερώτηση: \(Int(questionscount))/50"
        answerNumber = Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("N")}[QNumber].Answer

        for i in 0..<buttons.count{
            buttons[i].setTitle(Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("N")}[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        Questions.remove(at: QNumber)

    }else if Questions.count > 0 && questionscount < 24{
        QNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("A")}.count)))
        questionscount += 1
        questionLabel.text = Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("A")}[QNumber].Question

        self.title = "Ερώτηση: \(Int(questionscount))/50"
        answerNumber = Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("A")}[QNumber].Answer

        for i in 0..<buttons.count{
            buttons[i].setTitle(Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("A")}[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        Questions.remove(at: QNumber)

    }else if Questions.count > 0 && questionscount < 30{
        QNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("ΑΔ")}.count)))
        questionscount += 1
        questionLabel.text = Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("ΑΔ")}[QNumber].Question

        self.title = "Ερώτηση: \(Int(questionscount))/50"
        answerNumber = Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("ΑΔ")}[QNumber].Answer

        for i in 0..<buttons.count{
            buttons[i].setTitle(Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("ΑΔ")}[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        Questions.remove(at: QNumber)

    }else if Questions.count > 0 && questionscount < 35{
        QNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("ΕΠ")}.count)))
        questionscount += 1
        questionLabel.text = Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("ΕΠ")}[QNumber].Question

        self.title = "Ερώτηση: \(Int(questionscount))/50"
        answerNumber = Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("ΕΠ")}[QNumber].Answer

        for i in 0..<buttons.count{
            buttons[i].setTitle(Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("ΕΠ")}[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        Questions.remove(at: QNumber)

    }else if Questions.count > 0 && questionscount < 44{
        QNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("T")}.count)))
        questionscount += 1
        questionLabel.text = Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("T")}[QNumber].Question

        self.title = "Ερώτηση: \(Int(questionscount))/50"
        answerNumber = Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("T")}[QNumber].Answer

        for i in 0..<buttons.count{
            buttons[i].setTitle(Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("T")}[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        Questions.remove(at: QNumber)

    }else if Questions.count > 0 && questionscount < 50{
        QNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("ΑΝΘ")}.count)))
        questionscount += 1
        questionLabel.text = Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("ΑΝΘ")}[QNumber].Question

        self.title = "Ερώτηση: \(Int(questionscount))/50"
        answerNumber = Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("ΑΝΘ")}[QNumber].Answer

        for i in 0..<buttons.count{
            buttons[i].setTitle(Questions.filter{$0.Question.hasPrefix("ΑΝΘ")}[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        Questions.remove(at: QNumber)

    }else
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Σκόρ", message: "Απάντησες σωστά τις \(Int(score)) από τις \(Int(questionscount)) ερωτήσεις! \n \(String(format: "%.0f",(score/questionscount*100))) %", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Μενού", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { action in
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    Hide()
}
```

Comment: Check what you did, half of the time you are only changing the prefix. Might be worth a shot to create another function which will take prefix as an argument. Readability and maintainability will increase rapidly.

Answer (score 2):

Don't mess your logic with code.

### Follow this if you're concerned about Time Complexity - Difficult to implement

Just follow the algorithm below.

Since you have 8 groups create an integer array that is able to hold up to 8 values and initialize with all 0's

```
Array(1)  =   [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

And create another array that holds maximum questions that can be drawn from each group it looks like

```
Array(2)  =   [8 5 5 6 6 5 9 6]
```

Also, there should be an array for keeping number of questions remaining in each group

```
n[]   =  [ 8elements ] not mensioned in question
```

Lets start

**Loop**

1) Create a random number between 1-8 to choose the group

2) Check if the group has the maximum questions chosen already. By comparing array(1) and array(2) arrays if yes do step 1 once again.

3) Let maximum questions in a randomly selected group shall be n. Generate a random number between 1-n. Increase 1 to the corresponding position in the array(1) and reduce n by 1. Delete the selected question from group
   Check if you reached 50 questions
   If yes, quit
   If no, do step 4

4) Save your randomly selected question somewhere. And continue to step 1

It's better you append 50 questions into an array and put into the UI.

### This is when you don't consider complexity - Simple to implement

For this, you need to shuffle all the group of questions

[Refer this post shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24029847/5215474)

Then take first set of questions from each of groups(how much you want). It will be random.

**Advice to you: First solve the problem, then write code!**

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to make a new .json file with 8 groups of questions in 8 different groups, like questions1, questions2, etc.. after that with a switch make 8 cases and break every case if the number of questions picked randomly is the number you want for every group.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `data.json`, you are receiving a single list of 356 questions. The "8 groups* are simply group designations, with one "property" of each "question" being the group.

If you are actually receiving the data in *groups* of questions, then first step is to append them together into one group as you show here.

So, how to show 50 random questions, from that list of 356 questions?

- Generate an array of the numbers Zero through 355 (arrays are zero-based).
- Shuffle that array. Lots of good examples out there - here's a fairly comprehensive reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24029847/6257435

The first 50 elements of your array now contain random (no duplicates) values between 0 and 355, so you can simply show the actual questions in that order.

---

**Edit:**

If the requirement includes a pre-determined number of questions per group, that only adds a couple more steps:

Instead of using One big array of all 356 questions, split your json data into 8 arrays, each containing the questions belonging to a specific group.

Then, add those arrays to a two-dimensional array of "groups".

Next, build a two-dimensional array of question "ID" numbers - simply a sequence of 0 through number of questions in each group - and then shuffle each array.

The result will be X-number of random questions from each group.

Here is a simple example that you can run in a Playground page. The code generates a arrays of Question objects, and corresponding shuffled arrays of "indexes". Tapping the "Next Question" button will step through the result.

---

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// simple random number function
func random(_ range:Range<Int>) -> Int {
    return range.lowerBound + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)))
}

// shuffling extension
extension MutableCollection where Indices.Iterator.Element == Index {
    /// Shuffles the contents of this collection.
    mutating func shuffle() {
        let c = count
        guard c > 1 else { return }

        for (firstUnshuffled , unshuffledCount) in zip(indices, stride(from: c, to: 1, by: -1)) {
            let d: IndexDistance = numericCast(arc4random_uniform(numericCast(unshuffledCount)))
            guard d != 0 else { continue }
            let i = index(firstUnshuffled, offsetBy: d)
            swap(&self[firstUnshuffled], &self[i])
        }
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    /// Returns an array with the contents of this sequence, shuffled.
    func shuffled() -> [Iterator.Element] {
        var result = Array(self)
        result.shuffle()
        return result
    }
}

// Question object
struct Question {
    var Question: String!
    var Answers: [String]!
    var Answer: Int!

    init(item: [String: Any])
    {
        self.Question = item["Question"] as? String
        self.Answers = item["Answers"] as? [String]
        self.Answer = item["Answer"] as? Int
    }
}

// standard UIViewController
class TestViewController : UIViewController {

    // standard UIButton
    let btn: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.setTitle("  Next Question  ", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return b
    }()

    // standard UILabel
    let questionLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    // two-dimensional array of Question objects
    var arrayOfQuestions = [[Question]]()

    // two-dimension array of shuffled Index values
    var arrayOfIDs = [[Int]]()

    // number of questions per group
    let questionsPerGroup = [8, 5, 5, 6, 6, 5, 9, 6]

    // note: arrays are Zero-based, 
    //  so "first question" index will be Zero
    //  and "first group" index will be Zero

    // start Question counter at -1 so "next question" will be Zero
    var currentQuestion: Int = -1

    // group counter
    var currentGroup: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // this is just generating 8 groups of Questions that look like:
        // {"Question":"Group: 1 Question: 1", "Answers":["A", "B", "C", "D"], "Answer":1}

        for iGroup in 1...8 {

            //  each group will have between 43 and 48 questions
            let numQuestions = random(43..<49)

            // new empty array
            var aGroup = [Question]()

            for iQuestion in 1...numQuestions {

                let s: [String:Any] = [
                    "Question":"Group: \(iGroup) Question: \(iQuestion)",
                    "Answers":["A", "B", "C", "D"],
                    "Answer": random(0..<3)
                ]

                let q = Question(item: s)

                aGroup.append(q)

            }

            // append this "group" to the array
            arrayOfQuestions.append(aGroup)

            // create array of numbers 0 through number of questions -1
            let aIDs = Array(0..<numQuestions)

            // shuffle that array and append to "IDs" array
            arrayOfIDs.append(aIDs.shuffled())

        }

        // add a button and label to the view
        self.view.addSubview(btn)
        self.view.addSubview(questionLabel)

        btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40.0).isActive = true
        btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true

        questionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        questionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0).isActive = true
        questionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0).isActive = true

        // add touch up target to the button
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        // show the first question
        showNextQuestion()

    }

    func showNextQuestion() -> Void {

        // increment currentQuestion
        currentQuestion += 1

        // if we are past the number of questions in this group
        //  set currentQuestion back to Zero and increment currentGroup
        if currentQuestion == questionsPerGroup[currentGroup] {
            currentQuestion = 0
            currentGroup += 1
        }

        // if we are past the last group, show a message
        if currentGroup == questionsPerGroup.count {
            questionLabel.text = "End of quiz"
        } else {

            // get the question ID from the shuffled IDs of the current group
            let idx = arrayOfIDs[currentGroup][currentQuestion]

            // get that question object from the array
            let thisQuestion = arrayOfQuestions[currentGroup][idx]

            // get the question parts
            let sQuestion = thisQuestion.Question ?? "missing data"
            let aAnswers = thisQuestion.Answers ?? ["missing data"]
            let iAnswer = thisQuestion.Answer ?? -1

            // show them in our label
            questionLabel.text = "\nThis is Question: \(currentQuestion + 1) of Group: \(currentGroup + 1)\n\n" +
                "\(sQuestion)\n" +
                "\(aAnswers)\n" +
                "\(iAnswer)\n"
        }

    }

    func didTap(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        showNextQuestion()
    }

}

let vc = TestViewController()
vc.view.backgroundColor = .blue
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

Comment: If I append all the questions in an array, like I do, then do 8 if statements and say that on the first ‘if’ go and filter all elements contain ‘group1’ and pick only 8 elements from there and do the same for the other groups.. how it sounds to you?

Comment: For group2 pick 5 elements etc. till I reach 50 elements.

Comment: Do you need 8 from Group 1, 5 from Group 2, 5 from Group 3, 6 from group 4, etc....? Or do you just need 50 random questions, so you might have 1 from Group 1, Zero from Group 2, 17 from group 3, etc?