# Shuffle an Array of String using random() [Swift, Linux]

Tags: arrays, swift, linux

I am attempting to substitute arc4random in linux using the randr function from Glibc. Although I managed to shuffle an Array of integers, I failed to do so with an Array of string.

The code below works as expected:

```
import Foundation

extension MutableCollection {
    /// Shuffles the contents of this collection.
    mutating func shuffle() {
        let c = count
        guard c > 1 else { return }

        for (firstUnshuffled, unshuffledCount) in zip(indices, stride(from: c, to: 1, by: -1)) {
            let d: IndexDistance = numericCast(Int(random() % numericCast(unshuffledCount) + 1 ))
            let i = index(firstUnshuffled, offsetBy: d)
            swapAt(firstUnshuffled, i)
        }
    }
}

extension Sequence {
    /// Returns an array with the contents of this sequence, shuffled.
    func shuffled() -> [Element] {
        var result = Array(self)
        result.shuffle()
        return result
    }
}

let x = [1, 2, 3].shuffled()
print(x)
// [3, 1, 2]
```

But if I do the same to an Array of string:

```
let fiveStrings = ["20", "45", "70", "30"].map(String.init).shuffled()
print(fiveStrings)
```

It fails with `Index out of range`. The error is the same with

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(numbers.shuffle())
```

- How do I shuffle the strings using random()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
 let d: IndexDistance = numericCast(arc4random_uniform(numericCast(unshuffledCount)))
```

in [How do I shuffle an array in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift/24029847#24029847) creates a random number in the
between `0` and `unshuffledCount-1`. To achieve the same with 
`random()` use

```
 let d: IndexDistance = numericCast(Int(random() % numericCast(unshuffledCount)))
```

*without* the `+1`.

Note that in contrast to `arc4random_uniform()`:

- `random()` must be seeded, otherwise each run of the program will produce the same
  sequence of random numbers.
- `random() % upperBound` suffers from the "modulo bias", 
  compare [Why do people say there is modulo bias when using a random number generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984974/why-do-people-say-there-is-modulo-bias-when-using-a-random-number-generator).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. I know about the modulo bias, but that has to do for now.  How do I solve the problem in the line: `var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]; print(numbers.shuffle())`?

Comment: What problem? `shuffle()` has no return value, it mutates the argument. What you probably want is `var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4] ; numbers.shuffle() ; print(numbers)`