# Create a for loop by making sure that a different element of the array is used each time

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

This is my loop

```
for category in categories! {
    NearbyPlaces.getNearbyPlaces(by: category?.name ?? "food", coordinates: currentLocation!, radius: radius, token: self.response?.nextPageToken, completion: didReceiveResponse)  
}
```

where `categories` is an array with inside a list of categories of places (google places) (like restaurant, gym, bar) and i use it with a lot of other functions to search nearby places of those categories. My problem is this, now as it is now, it all works properly, so if in my array `categories` i have for example 2 elements: bar and gym and near to me there are 10 restaurants and 10 gyms, he will load in my tableView 10 restaurants and 10 gyms. But now that i added a limit to the loadable places i have a problem, if around me there are 10 restaurants and 10 gyms and the limit is (for example) 4, he will not load to me 2 restaurants and 2 gyms but 4 restaurants or 4 gyms, depends on what comes first in the array, so i would like to know how to modify the cycle so that it always uses a different element of the array (so one time use the element in the index 0, after the element in the index 1 etc.)

EDIT

you are right guys, but is not easy to explain clearly my problem, substantially i have two VC with both a tableView, in the first you can chose multiple categories of places (google places) who'll go to fill the array categories, in the second should load x places in x radius (geolocalization) based on the categories chosen in the previous controller, if i don't add a limit of places that can load in my tableview, the loop for does exactly the iterate through the categories one-by-one the PROBLEM is he does not load a place by category at a time but all places of the first item/category, then all places of the second etc. So if i add a limit for example 4 and i have two categories chosen in my array, he will not load 2 places of the first category and two of the second but if near to me (for example) there are 4 or more places of the type of the first category, he will load 4 places of the first type, so this is my problem

Comment: Your question is very vague. The for loop does already exactly what you seem to be asking for (iterate through the categories one-by-one). The question seems to be very related / dependent on the GooglePlaces API, but you don't mention that at all. Edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @fishinear i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you generate an array of possible matches for the category and then use `shuffle` to randomise the order of the results in the array. That way you should get a different set of matches each time (depending on how many actual results you have for the category of course)

[How do I shuffle an array in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

The question has much more to do with how the GooglePlaces API works, then with any for-loop. That said, and without knowing much about the GooglePlaces API, your best bet is probably **not** to restrict the number of results that GooglePlaces returns. Then sift through all the returned results yourself to select which ones you want to show.