# How to change the value of return array from function in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, immutability

I have return one function:

```swift
func abc() -> [Int] {
    return [1,2,3,4]
}
```

I'm calling this function and trying to modify the return value

`abc().sort()`

It gives this error:
`"Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'abc' returns immutable value".`

I know in order to change the value inside the function we need to use inout parameter but how to change the value which is returned from the function in swift?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value - not sure why value is immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287795/cannot-use-mutating-member-on-immutable-value-function-call-returns-immutable-v) (Specifically: Instead of using a mutating functions `shuffle()`, you can use a variant that returns a shuffled copy `shuffled()`, similar to `sort()` vs `sorted()`)

Answer (score 2):

You can only assign the result to a new variable with `sorted()`

```
let sortedArray = abc().sorted()
```