# Reading in array of elements from macOS directory

Tags: swift, macos, swift4

I can read in elements (images or videos) uploaded in Xcode's project this way:

```
let photos = (1...9).map {
    NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "000\($0)"))
}
```

or like this:

```
let videos = (1...100).map { _ in
    Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "mov", subdirectory: nil)![Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(100)))]
}
```

But how to read in files (as array) from macOS directory using `.map` method?

```
/Users/me/Desktop/ArrayOfElements/
```

Comment: Well, how would you go about accessing `/Users/me/Desktop/A/Singe/File.txt`?

Comment: let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/me/Desktop/A/Single/File.txt")

Comment: Good. Now, how given an `n: Int = 123`, how would you go about accessing `/Users/me/Desktop/A/Single/File123.txt`, using `n`?

Comment: That's what my question about!

Comment: I mean for the specific case of `n = 123`. How can you put the int `123` in that path, so that you can initialize a `URL` from it?

Comment: `But if I don't know how many files in my directory...` -> What have you tried to do to figure this out?

Comment: This directory is Library. There are many files at the moment or a few ones...

Comment: So? That doesn't mean you can't check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167587/discussion-between-alexander-and-andy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your second way is very expensive, the array of movie URLs is read a hundred times from the bundle. This is more efficient:

```
let resources = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "mov", subdirectory: nil)!
let videos = (1...100).map { _ in
    resources[Int(arc4random_uniform(100))]
}
```

Reading from `/Users/me/Desktop` is only possible if the application is **not** sandboxed, otherwise you can only read form the application container.

To get all files (as `[URL]`) from a directory use `FileManager`:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Desktop/ArrayOfElements")
do {
    let fileURLs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
    let movieURLs = fileURLs.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "mov" }
    print(movieURLs)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Rather than using `map` I recommend to implement an [Array extension adding `shuffle()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift)

Comment: Thank you very much, @vadian. But how can I use `.reversed()` method using FileManager?

Comment: The result is an array. You can use any function array responds to, amongst others `.reverse`

Comment: Where to put it? This is unfamiliar syntax for me.

Comment: At the end of the `FileManager` line `...options: [.skipsHiddenFiles]).reversed()`

Comment: Damn! Thanks a lot! ))

Comment: could you help me? I have an error after a first loop.

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range. I have 7 jpeg images in a folder. ArrayOfViews = 20. I published my code as an answer.

Comment: `arc4random_uniform` is zero-based. 7 photos is `arc4random_uniform(6)` – or better `arc4random_uniform(photos.count - 1)` – and you don't need the explicit `UInt32` initializer.

Comment: not working with 6, I tried it. Works with 1 only)) Strange. I suppose the error in let image = [NSImage(data: try Data(contentsOf: index))]

Comment: Please delete the answer and ask a new question. Answers shouldn't be misused for subsequent questions. And describe what you are going to accomplish.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49506602/random-photos-in-views-fatal-error-index-out-of-range