# Random photos in 12 views – Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: arrays, macos, loops, swift4

I've got `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range` looping my 7 photos from array in NSViews.

How to fix it?

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Desktop/ArrayOfElements")
do {
    let fileURLs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [.skipsHiddenFiles]).reversed()
    let photos = fileURLs.filter { $0.pathExtension == "jpg" }

    for index in photos {
        let image = [NSImage(data: try Data(contentsOf: index))]

        for view in arrayOfViews {
            let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(photos.count-1)))
            view.image = image[i]
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: I'm a fan of using:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329186/safe-bounds-checked-array-lookup-in-swift-through-optional-bindings

That way your code will never crash when fetching values from arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this line is wrong:
`view.image = image[i]`
image array has `length = 1`

Use `view.image = image[0]` instead

**EDIT**

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Desktop/ArrayOfElements")
do {
    let fileURLs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [.skipsHiddenFiles]).reversed()
    let photos = fileURLs.filter { $0.pathExtension == "jpg" }


        for view in arrayOfViews {
            let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(photos.count-1)))
            let image = NSImage(data: try Data(contentsOf: photos[i]))
            view.image = image
        }

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: But I need all photos not one.

Comment: you already loop over the photos `for index in photos` . Do you want to shuffle photo array?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a category to `Collection`

```
extension Collection where Index == Int {

    /**
     Gives a random element of the collection.

     - returns: A random element of the collection.
     */
    func randomElement() -> Iterator.Element? {
        return isEmpty ? nil : self[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(endIndex)))]
    }

}
```

Usage

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
let randomNumber = numbers.randomElement()
print(randomNumber!)
```

**Edit:**

I guess you are making mistake in the following code

```
for view in arrayOfViews {
    let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(photos.count-1)))
    view.image = image[i]
}
```

Let's assume `photos` objects having 10 elements and `image` object have less than 10 elements, so in such case, you will get this type of error. So change it to the following

```
for view in arrayOfViews {
    let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(image.endIndex)))
    view.image = image[i]
}
```