# Produced Numbers are must different each other with arc4random

Tags: ios, swift, random, arc4random

i want to use arc4random but produced Numbers are must different each other.

How do i do this example?

Comment: Put your numbers into an array. Shuffle it. Remove the numbers in order. See: [How to shuffle an array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24029847/1630618)

Comment: Can you show us the code that you tried and explain why it is not giving you what you wanted?

Comment: i don't want to shuffle numbers in array. i want to different produced numbers in array.

Comment: Do you want random numbers in the full range of `arc4random()` (from 0 to 2³²). If not, you should use `arc4random_uniform(_:)` to limit the range of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
let desired = 20
var randomSet: Set<Int> = [] //Sets guarantee uniqueness
var array: [Int] = [] //Use arrays to guarantee the order

while array.count < desired {
    let random = Int(arc4random())
    if !randomSet.contains(random) {
        array.append(random)
        randomSet.insert(random)
    }
}
```

Or, using LeoDaubus' suggestion:

```
while array.count < desired {
    let random = Int(arc4random())
    if randomSet.insert(random).inserted {
        array.append(random)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the inserted property?

Comment: `randomSet.insert(random).inserted ?
        array.append(random) : ()`

Comment: @LeoDabus, I see your point about using `inserted`, but why use the ternary operator like that, with side-effects void conditions? Seems needlessly obtuse. I'd much rather say `if randomSet.insert(random).inserted { array.append(random) }`. That seems a **lot** clearer.

Comment: It is not an empty tuple, it is Void

Comment: Sorry, void. My comment stands. Seems needlessly cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set` to easily achieve this:

```
var randomSet: Set<Int> = [] //Sets guarantee uniqueness
var array: [Int] = [] //Use arrays to guarantee the order
while randomSet.count < 2 {
    randomSet.insert(Int(arc4random())) //Whatever random number generator you use
}
for number in randomSet {
    array.append(number)
}
//Now you can use the array for your operations
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you

Comment: Note that using a set you will lose the original order

Comment: After creating the set of numbers, why not use `var array = Array(randomSet)`? (The `Array` type has an initializer that takes a `Set` as it's input.)

Comment: @DuncanC this will discard the original order which the elements where inserted

Comment: @LeoDabus true, but does the original order matter with *random* numbers? If you want to preserve the original order you could use a set to validate the uniqueness and add one number at a time to your array.

Comment: What is memberAfterInsert? Where is it defined? I can't find it.

Comment: It is one of the values returned by the set insert method. `mutating func insert(_ newMember: Int) -> (inserted: Bool, memberAfterInsert: Int)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set to check if the random number was inserted appending the member after checking if it was inserted:

```
var set: Set<Int> = []
var randomElements: [Int] = []
let numberOfElements = 10
while set.count < numberOfElements {
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(10))  //  0...9
    set.insert(random).inserted ? randomElements.append(random) : ()
}
print(randomElements) // "[5, 2, 8, 0, 7, 1, 4, 3, 6, 9]\n"
```