# How to pull random questions for quizz app from an array in questionbank? Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, random, shuffle

So I am working on my first personal project (includes a quiz feature), while at the same time taking a swift course. I am trying to figure out, how to randomize the arrays.

I've found a few videos explaining something similar, but nothing seems to work for me.

This is an example of one of my question banks that needs to be shuffled.

```
class ImageQuestionBank {
var list = [ImageQuestion] ()
init () {
    let item = ImageQuestion(qtext: "Example Question?", image: "image1", correctAnswer: true)
    list.append(item)
    list.append(ImageQuestion(qtext: "Example Question?", image: "image2", correctAnswer: false))
    list.append(ImageQuestion(qtext: "Example Question?", image: "image3", correctAnswer: true))
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is shuffled() or shuffle() not working for you?

Answer (score 2):

As @Retterdesdialogs comment suggests, you can use `shuffled()` *which returns the elements of the sequence, shuffled.* or `shuffle()` for *in place shuffle*

But, instead of shuffling of an array, **which is a costly operation**, use `Int` `random` function to get random int between given range.

```
let randomInt = Int.random(in: 0..<list.count) // this will give a random int value between 0 and list count.
```

Now fetch item using `randomInt`

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Use `arc4random_uniform(list.count)` to generate the random index for `list` object. But to make sure a question will not repeat for that maintain a `askedQuestionList`. And before showing the question to user check question entry in `askedQuestionList`.

Another approach shuffle your question array, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift).