# How do I shuffle an array of Images without .shuffle as simply as possible- nothing complicated

Tags: arrays, swift, shuffle

I was working on something and wondering if I could shuffle an array of images without using `.shuffle` in Swift.

Here's my array:

```
var deck: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "2c.png")!, UIImage(named: "2h.png")!, UIImage(named: "2d.png")!, UIImage(named: "2s.png")!, UIImage(named: "3c.png")! ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I shuffle an array in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24026510/2108547)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve your own custom `shuffle` method for `Collection` type.

For example:

```
extension Array {
    var yourShuffled: [Element] {
        return map{ (arc4random(), $0) }
               .sorted{ $0.0 < $1.0 }
               .map{ $0.1 }
    }
}
```

copied from [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/shuffle-an-array/discuss/116191/Declarative-Solutions-in-Swift-and-JavaScript)

Comment: Don't copy from leet code ;).  That algorithm is O(nlog(n)) when it should be O(n).

Comment: Thx, `sorted ` is `O(nlog(n))`

Comment: is there no simpler way to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026510/how-do-i-shuffle-an-array-in-swift#answer-29541686